# How to remove old versions of Eclipse plugins?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

After update, old Eclipse plugins remain in "plugins" folder (there are also leftovers in "features" folder).

Is there a way to remove those automatically?

Comment: Oh my. What a mess. My eclipse install isn't too old but already has dozens of duplicate plugins, some with 40MB jars. And apparently, Eclipse doesn't always use the latest version.

Answer (score 14):

I use the following command:

```
eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application -profile epp.package.jee
```

**Notes:**

1. This is documented in [Equinox/p2/FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/FAQ#Why_aren.27t_bundles_being_removed_when_their_associated_feature_has_been_removed.3F), see "Why aren't bundles being removed when their associated feature has been removed?"

   The FAQ answer references [an Eclipse Community Forum thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=543500) "Plug-in jar remains after feature uninstall" (June 2010) as the origin for this recipe.

   The recipe is still valid nowadays, with Eclipse 4.8 Photon.
2. The `-profile` argument depends on what packaging of Eclipse IDE you are using. The above one (`epp.package.jee`) is for "Eclipse for Java EE Developers". I found it in the file `configuration/config.ini`. The relevant line there is the following:

   ```
   eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.jee
   ```

Comment: Many upvoted answers are very old, and correspond to old times. This one is much more up-to-date and works like a charm. I wish I could upvote more.

Comment: This method worked for me.  In Help->Install New Software->Click on "already installed", Installation History tab, Selected old previous configurations, then delete.  Then found config.ini to get the valid eclipse.p2.profile value.  Then in windows powershell run eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application -profile DefaultProfile

Comment: This command does not work correctly if you had updated manually by copying a new Eclipse installation over an existing installation. In such a case the new installation is removed, instead of the old one (-> the installation is reverted to the old version).

Comment: Robert, maybe you have not updated all the necessary configuration files. Note that if one wants to install a plugin manually, by copying its files, the documented place to put such plugins is the "dropins" directory.

Answer (score 8):

To get rid of the old plugins you have to clear the Installation History. Go to Help | About Eclipse | Installation Details | Installation History and select all the old stuff. Then click delete and restart. Voila. This works with Eclipse Helios (3.6)

Comment: This did not delete any old plugins for me (Eclipse 3.7, even doing `eclipse -clean` afterwards).

Answer (score 6):

I also want to remove old plugins, but still found no answer today, so I wrote a quick and dirty script `guess-old-eclipse-plugins.sh` to handle old plugins.

This script will scan plugins directory under Eclipse directory. and will generate a `remove-old-eclipse-plugins.txt` file which can be used to remove old plugins.

This script is tested under Cygwin 1.7.15 on Windows XP.

## guess-old-eclipse-plugins.sh

```sh
PluginsDir=plugins
FeaturesDir=features
PluginIDSeparator=_
RemovingScriptFileName=remove-old-eclipse-plugins.txt
rm -rf $RemovingScriptFileName

#for dir in $PluginsDir $FeaturesDir
for dir in $PluginsDir  # $FeaturesDir: most file names in features dir contains more than 1 _ character
do
    echo "Processing [$dir] directory..."
    # split PluginID from filename
    # (not reliable, but general working. (ex: will get one junit PluginID because there're move than 1 _ characters in file name))
    file_list=$(ls $dir);
    echo "$file_list" | cut -f1 -d $PluginIDSeparator         > $dir-all.txt
    echo "$file_list" | cut -f1 -d $PluginIDSeparator  | uniq > $dir-uniq.txt

    # get the PluginList which VERY POSSIBLY has old versions
    diff_result=$(diff -U 0 $dir-uniq.txt $dir-all.txt)
    plugins_which_has_old_versions=$(echo "$diff_result" | grep -e "^+[^+]" | cut -f 2 -d +)

    #
    for p in $(echo "$plugins_which_has_old_versions")
    do
        echo "$p"
        i=0
        for f in $(ls -d -t $dir/$p$PluginIDSeparator*) # use 'ls' command, can sort result by file time, but can not handle file name contains special characters (white space) when using wildcard
        #for f in $(find $dir -name "$p$PluginIDSeparator*")    # use 'find' command
        do
            if [ -d $f ]
            then
                # should use rm -rf
                echo -n "[D]"
            else
                echo -n "   "
            fi
            echo -n "$f"

            ((i++))
            if [ $i -eq 1 ]
            then
                echo ""
                continue    # first file, the newest version
            fi
            echo "    [old]"
            echo "rm -rf $f" >> $RemovingScriptFileName
        done

        echo
    done
done
```

## IMPORTANT NOTICE

Before use the generated `remove-old-eclipse-plugins.txt` file to remove plugins, make sure all the listed plugins in it are **REALLY** old plugins. Because, this script can't handle file name contains more than 1 `_` characters. For example: JUnit v3 and v4 plugins are 2 *different* plugins, but the script will treat it as **same** plugins because these 2 file names use same `org.junit_` prefix.

```
org.junit
[D]plugins/org.junit_3.8.2.v3_8_2_v20100427-1100
[D]plugins/org.junit_4.8.2.v4_8_2_v20110321-1705    [old]  <-- wrong
```

So, **use it VERY CAREFULLY**, remove the wrong part before use it, or your Eclipse IDE may not work properly.

## Sample output

```
$ ./guess-old-eclipse-plugins.sh
Processing [plugins] directory...
org.eclipse.gef
   plugins/org.eclipse.gef_3.7.2.v20111106-2020.jar
   plugins/org.eclipse.gef_3.6.2.v20110110-2020.jar    [old]

org.eclipse.help.base
   plugins/org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.2.v201202080800.jar
   plugins/org.eclipse.help.base_3.5.3.v201102101200.jar    [old]

org.eclipse.help.ui
   plugins/org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.101.r37_20110819.jar
   plugins/org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.3.r36_20101116.jar    [old]
...
```

## Sample generated script

```
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.gef_3.6.2.v20110110-2020.jar
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.help.base_3.5.3.v201102101200.jar
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.3.r36_20101116.jar
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.5.3.r36_20101130.jar
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core_3.3.402.R36_v20110120-1000.jar
rm -rf plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui_3.5.2.v20100928a_r362.jar
```

Answer (score 6):

Removing old plugins is always a hassle. Especially when you upgrade and your Eclipse just doesn't want to start again and you need to figure it out via the metadata hell of plugins dependencies.

I've seen that couple of you tried to fix this via a script.

## Eclipse Plugin Cleaner

Well I have created a **java based tool** (**with tests, build by maven & hosted at github, so you are free to fork it**) that checks for duplicities of plugins by introspecting manifest files (or file names if the manifest is incomplete or corrupted).

## Now

you can quite easily for example download the latest Eclipse and put your old Eclipse into `dropins/eclipse` folder and the tool will clean up the dropins folder - thus your new bundles are preserved and old one are deleted (The `dropins` folder is prefered for deletion if 2 or more same versions are found).

More information about the **Eclipse Plugin Cleaner** can be found at https://github.com/azachar/eclipse-plugin-cleaner

Answer (score 5):

Instead of sorting, etc. the solutions should be based on the contents of `bundles.info`.

Manual solution:

- create a copy of `eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info`
- edit
- search for regular expression: `.*plugins/([^,]*),.*`, replace with: `$1` (e.g. using **Notepad++**)
- go to `eclipse/plugin/`
- select files and folders listed in this new file (e.g. in **Total Commander**: *Mark > Load Selection From File*)
- invert selection
- delete/move selected files and folders

Answer (score 4):

I've modified the script to allow for all dropins, features, and plugins.
First it relies on reverse sort to guess the most recent canonical plugin version.

Next it reduces that qualified plugin version name to a canonical plugin sed expression.
If the plugin is the first match for this expression it stores its pattern and keeps it, otherwise it is an old stale version and it flags it for deletion.

```
# scan_old_plugins.sh

# script to scan for duplicate old eclipse features, plugins and dropins
# generates a "clean-old-plugins.sh" script to clean old versions.
# warning: DANGEROUS! review clean-old-plugins script before running it.

DropinsDir=dropins
FeaturesDir=features
PluginsDir=plugins

CanonicalPluginsFile=sed_canonical_plugins.sh
CleanPluginScriptFile=clean_old_plugins.sh

echo "" > $CanonicalPluginsFile
echo "" > $CleanPluginScriptFile

#for dir in $PluginsDir
for dir in $FeaturesDir $PluginsDir $DropinsDir
do
    echo "Processing [$dir] directory..."
    # 
    file_list=$(\ls -1 $dir | sort -r);
    echo "$file_list" > $dir-all.txt

    #
    for p in $(echo "$file_list")
    do
        v=$(echo $p | sed -e 's/_[0-9\._\-]*/_.*/g' | sed -e 's/[0-9][0-9]*/.*/g')
        g=$(grep -l "$v" $CanonicalPluginsFile | head -1 | awk '{print $1}')
        if [ "$g" = "" ]; then
            echo "$p=keep";
            echo "$v=$p" >>  $CanonicalPluginsFile
        else
            echo "$p=stale";
            echo "rm -rf $p" >> $CleanPluginScriptFile
        fi
        
    done
done
```

Comment: echo "rm -rf $dir$p" >> $CleanPluginScriptFile

Answer (score 3):

For me this works:

```
eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application -profile SDKProfile
```

Tested Eclipse v4.9. Removes old version of my plugins.
The profile `epp.package.jee` mentioned in other solutions returns "not existing" for me.

Answer (score 2):

With Ganymede (3.4), the correct way to manage your plugins would be to drop them in the '**dropins**' folder:

```
\[eclipse\]/dropins/eclemma1.3.1/eclipse/(plugins|features)
```

That plugin will be detected by the 'p2' provisioning mechanism and used, but ***not copied in the plugins and features directories of eclipse***. It stays in the dropins folder.

When you will drop eclemma1.3.2, all you have to do is delete eclemma1.3.1 from your dropins directory, and that old version is gone.

Comment: I have Aptana, FileSync, AJDT and whatnot, all installed from update sites. They all deployed to "plugins". The only one I have in "dropins" is jadclipse.

Comment: Ok, you can try to 'move' those plugins from eclipse/plugins and eclipse/feature to dropins/FileSync/eclipse/(plugins|features) and dropins/AJDT/eclipse/... and so on. And see if you can better manage your plugins from there.

Comment: Identifying right versions and moving that many jars by hand is the task equal to the question I asked. Also, I'd loose auto-update capability.

Comment: the auto-update should be preserved, since p2 manage plugins in dropins folder the same way it monitors the one in eclipse. As for moving the right files, just get a fresh install of eclipse (not Aptana) and do a compare folder btw. eclipse/... and Aptana/...: the extra ones need to be moved ;)

Comment: This one doesn't work for me either. Wherever the plugins are, in the "dropins" or "plugins" folder, after few updates old versions start to pile up (if indeed p2 manages "dropins" as well).

Comment: p2 is all about managing 'dropins' directory, and at least that gives you only one place where you have to remove old plugins. So when you say "start to pile up", do you mean "pile up in the dropins directory" ?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse allows you to revert back to any previous configuration (go to the Help menu, then "Software Updates"). My guess is that Eclipse won't remove these old versions, or this functionality would no longer work.

If when you restart Eclipse you provide the "-clean" argument, it performs various cleanup operations, but for reasons stated above I don't think it will remove old plugins/features.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a script in python to move the old plugins to a backup folder, so if something goes wrong it can go back. 
The script has two modes of operation: Manual mode asks you what to do with each duplicated plugin detected, and automatic only question in cases where the length of the string has changed and therefore may have changed the system, or version numbering.

I hope this helps someone

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import re
from datetime import datetime

directory="C:\\eclipse64\\plugins"
dirBackup="C:\\eclipse64\\PluginsBackup"        #This folder is a kind of recycle bin for save deleted plugins. In case you have problems running eclipse after remove them you can restore them. If you don't detect any problem you can erase this folder to save disk space
manual=False    #Verifying deletion of each plugin manually (True) or automatic (False) 

def globRegEx(directory,pat,absolutePath=True,type_=0):
    '''Function that given a directory and a regular pattern returns a list of files that meets the pattern

    :param str directory: Base path where we search for files that meet the pattern
    :param str pat: Regular expression that selected files must match 
    :param bool absolutePath: Optional parameter that indicates if the returned list contains absolute (True) or relative paths (False)
    :param int type_: Type of selection 0: selects files and directories 1: only selects files 2: only selects directories
    :return: a list with the paths that meet the regular pattern
    '''
    names=os.listdir(directory)
    pat=re.compile(pat)
    res=[]

    for name in names:
        if pat.match(name):
            path=directory+os.sep+name

            if type_==1 and os.path.isfile(path):
                res.append(path if absolutePath else name)
            elif type_==2 and os.path.isdir(path):
                res.append(path if absolutePath else name)
            elif type_==0:
                res.append(path if absolutePath else name)

    return(res)

def processRepeated(repList):
    ''' this function is responsible for leaving only the newer version of the plugin
    '''

    if repList and len(repList)>1:     #If the plugin is repeated
        repList.sort(reverse=True)
        print("Repeated plugins found:")
        min=len(repList[0])    # If strings haven't got the same length indicates a change in the numeration version system
        max=min
        newer=datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
        sel=0

        for i,path in enumerate(repList):
            lr=len(path)
            modifDate=datetime.fromtimestamp((os.path.getctime(path)))
            if modifDate>newer:     #Keep the last creation date and its index
                newer=modifDate
                sel=i+1

            if lr<min: 
                min=lr
            elif lr>max: 
                max=lr

            print(str(i+1) + " " + modifDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + ": " + path)
        print(" ")

        if manual or min!=max:      #If manual mode is enabled or if there is a string length diference between different version of plugins
            selec=raw_input("Which version do you want to keep?: ["+str(sel)+"] ")
            if selec:
                selec=int(selec)
            else: 
                selec=sel   #Newer is the Default value
        else:
            selec=1


        del(repList[selec-1])      #Delete selected plugin from the list

        for path in repList:  #Move the rest of the list to the backup folder
            print("Deleting: "+ path)
            os.renames(path,os.path.join(dirBackup,os.path.basename(path)))

        print("-------------------------------------\n\n")

def main():

    filePlugins=globRegEx(directory,"^.*$",False,1)      #Creates a list with all the files only
    dirPlugins=globRegEx(directory,"^.*$",False,2)       #Creates a list with all the folders only


    #Process files first

    for plugin in filePlugins:
        m=re.match(r"(.*_)\d.*?\.jar$",plugin)   #Creates the glob pattern
        if m:
            patAux=m.groups()[0]+".*?\.jar$"
            find=globRegEx(directory,patAux,True,1)
            processRepeated(find)

    #Now Directories 

    for plugin in dirPlugins:
        m=re.match(r"(.*_)\d.*$",plugin)   #Creates the glob pattern
        if m:
            patAux=m.groups()[0]+".*$"
            find=globRegEx(directory,patAux,True,2)
            processRepeated(find)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

For STM32CubeIDE, a popular Eclipse-based IDE for the STM32 microcontroller-family, this command did clean-up old plugin versions under Windows 10:

```
"C:\ST\STM32CubeIDE_1.3.0\STM32CubeIDE\eclipsec" -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application -profile STM32CubeIDE
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple, clean and efficient solution is to simply delete the current Eclipse installation and install the latest Eclipse version (or reinstall the current version).

- The key is to install Eclipse via the zip package rather than the installer or **Install / Update**.
- See: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/
- e.g. Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers: `eclipse-java-2021-06-R-win32-x86_64.zip`
- Note: All of the Eclipse user preferences are persevered because they are stored in your Eclipse workspace.

#### Steps

- (1) Manually delete the existing `eclipse` directory containing the current Eclipse installation
- (2) Download the latest Eclipse IDE zip file

  - https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/
- (3) Unzip the latest Eclipse IDE zip file to the `eclipse` directory
- (4) Start the latest Eclipse IDE
- (5) Select your existing Eclipse workspace
- (6) Perform the Eclipse workspace migration if prompted

  - Note: Back-up workspace if paranoid (prior to this step)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to automate removal by configuring Equinox:

- [Is there any method to clean old plugins/features from disk automatically once new plugin/features are installed in eclipse RCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64569217/is-there-any-method-to-clean-old-plugins-features-from-disk-automatically-once-n)
- https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/FAQ#Why_aren.27t_bundles_being_removed_when_their_associated_feature_has_been_removed.3F

Configure your product to invoke a GC on startup by adding the following line to your product's `plugin_customization.ini` (requires the `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler` bundle):

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler/gcOnStartup=true
```

Manual: Run the garbage collector application:

```
eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application -profile SDKProfile
```