# Eclipse Debugger Hangs on Mac OSX

Tags: eclipse, debugging, macos, eclipse-pdt

I consider myself to be a seasoned Eclipse veteran, familiar with a variety of installs and configurations.  However, I'm currently unable to get the debugger in Eclipse Helios to work on my Mac.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Using:

- Mac OSX 10.6.7
- Eclipse Helios PDT Cocao 64-bit
- PHP 5.2.9 (XAMPP 1.0.1)
- JRE 1.6.0

Tried both Zend Debugger and Xedug.for 5.2.x
Debuggers were each separately, properly installed and verified with php_info().

When launching a page in debug mode, Eclipse hangs for about a minute then throws a heap stack error.  On a personal note, I've set up Eclipse PDT + XAMPP/MAMP + Zend/Xdebug numerous times on both Windows and Mac, and never seen this error.  I'm really at a loss here.  Looking forward to your comments!

Comment: I don't use the PHP toolings in Eclipse, but I do use Eclipse on a Mac, so maybe I can help a bit.  I would try two things:  first, moving to a Cocoa 32 bit build instead of a 64 bit build.  It seems more stable and uses less memory.  Second, have you tried upping the amount of memory you give to Eclipse?  (And permgen space, too!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ed!

The answer was indeed memory related.  For those of you coming from the PC world like myself, the Mac version of Eclipse PDT uses *way* more memory.

The answer?

- Downgrade to the 32 bit version.
- [Up the memory Eclipse is allowed to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334102/eclipse-memory-settings-when-getting-java-heap-space-and-out-of-memory), by a lot.
- Close any un-used projects.

**The last one was key.**  I used to leave all my projects open and never had any problems.  In order to get things to run on Mac, I had to close all projects except the one I was attempting to debug.