# Correct FlashBuilder.ini / eclipse.ini setting for use with profiler

Tags: apache-flex, profiling, flash-builder

My FlashBuilder instance keeps on crashing while doing some heavy profiling.
Must say though that I am also generating object allocation traces (all, not the default 10) and traversing GC paths a lot.

However I have a hunch that I can solve this by allowing Flash Builder to use more memory.

This is my FlashBuilder.ini:

```
-startup
eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-nl
en_US
-vmargs
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:PermSize=64m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=eclipse/dropins
-Declipse.application=com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.FlashBuilderApplication
```

In my eclipse error log I can clearly see:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 1024000 bytes for GrET in C:\BUILD_AREA\jdk6_16\hotspot\src\share\vm\utilities\growableArray.cpp. Out of swap space?
```

Here is the full error log:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 1024000 bytes for GrET in C:\BUILD_AREA\jdk6_16\hotspot\src\share\vm\utilities\growableArray.cpp. Out of swap space?
#
#  Internal Error (allocation.inline.hpp:39), pid=3104, tid=3128
#  Error: GrET in C:\BUILD_AREA\jdk6_16\hotspot\src\share\vm\utilities\growableArray.cpp
#
# JRE version: 6.0_16-b01
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (14.2-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x01727800):  VMThread [stack: 0x54140000,0x54240000] [id=3128]

Stack: [0x54140000,0x54240000],  sp=0x5423fa64,  free space=1022k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x1e66c7]
V  [jvm.dll+0xa0c9c]
V  [jvm.dll+0xce307]
V  [jvm.dll+0xb4e97]
V  [jvm.dll+0xdc547]
V  [jvm.dll+0x16b5ee]
V  [jvm.dll+0x15955a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1d48b4]
V  [jvm.dll+0x19632d]
V  [jvm.dll+0xc69ff]
V  [jvm.dll+0xc866c]
V  [jvm.dll+0xc89c0]
V  [jvm.dll+0xcc99a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1cb122]
V  [jvm.dll+0xc79f5]
V  [jvm.dll+0xc7de1]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1e6b9d]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1e92a3]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1e853e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1e888c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1e8cb2]
V  [jvm.dll+0x173e5c]
C  [MSVCR71.dll+0x9565]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x4ed6c]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x6377b]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x6374e]

VM_Operation (0x5b51f80c): GenCollectFull, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x555c6800


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x555c6400 JavaThread "Worker-18" [_thread_blocked, id=1024, stack(0x5d080000,0x5d180000)]
  0x555c1400 JavaThread "Worker-16" [_thread_blocked, id=5780, stack(0x56a10000,0x56b10000)]
  0x555c4000 JavaThread "Worker-15" [_thread_blocked, id=968, stack(0x56410000,0x56510000)]
  0x555c2800 JavaThread "Worker-14" [_thread_blocked, id=5804, stack(0x58fa0000,0x590a0000)]
  0x580b6000 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3432, stack(0x56610000,0x56710000)]
  0x580b6c00 JavaThread "Thread-29" [_thread_in_native, id=4088, stack(0x56510000,0x56610000)]
  0x580b4c00 JavaThread "[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1148, stack(0x5bfb0000,0x5c0b0000)]
  0x555c6800 JavaThread "Worker-7" [_thread_blocked, id=4324, stack(0x5b420000,0x5b520000)]
  0x555c0400 JavaThread "Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=5952, stack(0x01870000,0x01970000)]
  0x555c5000 JavaThread "com.adobe.flexide.editorcore.editor.IdleTypingReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1404, stack(0x5aa10000,0x5ab10000)]
  0x555c4c00 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5484, stack(0x5a910000,0x5aa10000)]
  0x57c65000 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5208, stack(0x588d0000,0x589d0000)]
  0x57c3cc00 JavaThread "Thread-3" [_thread_in_native, id=5132, stack(0x587d0000,0x588d0000)]
  0x555f3c00 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=2704, stack(0x559b0000,0x55ab0000)]
  0x54c9f800 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3496, stack(0x554b0000,0x555b0000)]
  0x54bfcc00 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4556, stack(0x552b0000,0x553b0000)]
  0x54c34c00 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=240, stack(0x551b0000,0x552b0000)]
  0x54c34400 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4564, stack(0x56050000,0x56150000)]
  0x54b02800 JavaThread "Framework Active Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=4592, stack(0x55f50000,0x56050000)]
  0x0176f000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5252, stack(0x548a0000,0x549a0000)]
  0x01768000 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4436, stack(0x547a0000,0x548a0000)]
  0x01767800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=932, stack(0x546a0000,0x547a0000)]
  0x0175cc00 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4216, stack(0x545a0000,0x546a0000)]
  0x0172ec00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4780, stack(0x544a0000,0x545a0000)]
  0x0172a400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=860, stack(0x543a0000,0x544a0000)]
  0x01865000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=4172, stack(0x00030000,0x00130000)]

Other Threads:
=>0x01727800 VMThread [stack: 0x54140000,0x54240000] [id=3128]
  0x01770800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x549a0000,0x54aa0000] [id=4080]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x01869ca8] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x01727800
[0x0186a0b8] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x555c6800

Heap
 def new generation   total 45696K, used 22370K [0x03c20000, 0x06db0000, 0x08ae0000)
  eden space 40640K,  52% used [0x03c20000, 0x050d4e48, 0x063d0000)
  from space 5056K,  23% used [0x063d0000, 0x064f3b30, 0x068c0000)
  to   space 5056K,   0% used [0x068c0000, 0x068c0000, 0x06db0000)
 tenured generation   total 607960K, used 379895K [0x08ae0000, 0x2dc96000, 0x43c20000)
   the space 607960K,  62% used [0x08ae0000, 0x1fdddfe0, 0x1fdde000, 0x2dc96000)
 compacting perm gen  total 78592K, used 78435K [0x43c20000, 0x488e0000, 0x53c20000)
   the space 78592K,  99% used [0x43c20000, 0x488b8c10, 0x488b8e00, 0x488e0000)
No shared spaces configured.

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x0040d000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\FlashBuilder.exe
0x77cd0000 - 0x77e0c000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x765b0000 - 0x76684000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x75ec0000 - 0x75f0a000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x77e20000 - 0x77ee9000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x761c0000 - 0x7620e000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x77e10000 - 0x77e1a000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x76120000 - 0x761bd000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x77c20000 - 0x77ccc000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x74d70000 - 0x74f0e000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
0x77af0000 - 0x77b47000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x76b50000 - 0x76b6f000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x77b50000 - 0x77c1c000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x72000000 - 0x7200f000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502\eclipse_1406.dll
0x77a50000 - 0x77af0000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x76480000 - 0x76499000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x76690000 - 0x76731000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x72b60000 - 0x72c03000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_50916076bcb9a742\MSVCR90.dll
0x75310000 - 0x75319000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x6d710000 - 0x6d732000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\jre\bin\splashscreen.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR71.dll
0x6d800000 - 0x6da8b000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x74630000 - 0x74662000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x75d50000 - 0x75d9c000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x74d30000 - 0x74d70000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x6d7b0000 - 0x6d7bc000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x6d330000 - 0x6d34f000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\jre\bin\java.dll
0x6d290000 - 0x6d298000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\jre\bin\hpi.dll
0x77ef0000 - 0x77ef5000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6d7ff000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x767a0000 - 0x768fc000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x75da0000 - 0x75dac000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x76b70000 - 0x76bff000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.DLL
0x758a0000 - 0x758b6000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x75640000 - 0x7567b000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x75470000 - 0x75487000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x75e20000 - 0x75e2b000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x6d610000 - 0x6d623000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\jre\bin\net.dll
0x76220000 - 0x76255000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x765a0000 - 0x765a6000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x75860000 - 0x7589c000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x75850000 - 0x75856000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x73b00000 - 0x73b10000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x71fe0000 - 0x71ff0000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x71fc0000 - 0x71fd2000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x75720000 - 0x75764000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x71fa0000 - 0x71fa8000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x753a0000 - 0x753a5000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x73720000 - 0x7373c000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x73700000 - 0x73707000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x71fb0000 - 0x71fb6000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x73590000 - 0x735c8000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x6d630000 - 0x6d639000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x542d0000 - 0x5433e000     C:\Users\*******\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\cascaded\328916\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\546\1\.cp\swt-win32-3735.dll
0x76260000 - 0x762db000     C:\Windows\system32\comdlg32.dll
0x76d70000 - 0x779ba000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x764a0000 - 0x76595000     C:\Windows\system32\WININET.dll
0x76c30000 - 0x76d67000     C:\Windows\system32\urlmon.dll
0x75fa0000 - 0x760be000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x75e90000 - 0x75e9c000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x76950000 - 0x76b4e000     C:\Windows\system32\iertutil.dll
0x74900000 - 0x74913000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x74920000 - 0x74a15000     C:\Windows\system32\propsys.dll
0x779c0000 - 0x77a43000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x6cd90000 - 0x6cd99000     C:\Windows\system32\LINKINFO.dll
0x54270000 - 0x5428d000     C:\Users\*******\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\cascaded\328916\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\546\1\.cp\swt-gdip-win32-3735.dll
0x74ba0000 - 0x74d30000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.17825_none_72d273598668a06b\gdiplus.dll
0x747d0000 - 0x748cb000     C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x74100000 - 0x7413c000     C:\Windows\system32\oleacc.dll
0x54e90000 - 0x54e9e000     C:\Users\*******\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\cascaded\328916\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\232\1\.cp\os\win32\x86\localfile_1_0_0.dll
0x54ef0000 - 0x54ef8000     C:\Users\*******\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\cascaded\328916\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\242\1\.cp\os\win32\x86\win32refresh.dll
0x55b30000 - 0x55b71000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexide.nativelibs_4.6.0.328916\os\win32\x86\BridgeTalk.dll
0x6fdc0000 - 0x6fe2a000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexide.nativelibs_4.6.0.328916\libs\adobe_caps.dll
0x762e0000 - 0x7647d000     C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x760f0000 - 0x76117000     C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x75ea0000 - 0x75eb2000     C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x752e0000 - 0x75301000     C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
0x76900000 - 0x76945000     C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x55cb0000 - 0x55d67000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.utils.osnative_4.6.0.328916\os\win32\x86\JNIToNativeBridge.dll
0x55ba0000 - 0x55bab000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexide.amt_4.6.0.328916\os\win32\x86\amt_win_jnilib.dll
0x71460000 - 0x714ee000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_50916076bcb9a742\MSVCP90.dll
0x633a0000 - 0x63490000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexide.amt_4.6.0.328916\os\win32\x86\amtlib.dll
0x63280000 - 0x63395000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexide.amt_4.6.0.328916\os\win32\x86\amtservices.dll
0x72090000 - 0x720e8000     C:\Windows\system32\WINHTTP.dll
0x72040000 - 0x7208f000     C:\Windows\system32\webio.dll
0x6cd20000 - 0x6cd8a000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexide.amt_4.6.0.328916\os\win32\x86\adobe_caps.dll
0x55ed0000 - 0x55ef8000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexide.amt_4.6.0.328916\os\win32\x86\asneu.dll
0x71ad0000 - 0x71ada000     C:\Windows\system32\wbem\wbemprox.dll
0x71d30000 - 0x71d8c000     C:\Windows\system32\wbemcomn.dll
0x75e10000 - 0x75e1e000     C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
0x71560000 - 0x7156f000     C:\Windows\system32\wbem\wbemsvc.dll
0x71ba0000 - 0x71c36000     C:\Windows\system32\wbem\fastprox.dll
0x71ae0000 - 0x71af8000     C:\Windows\system32\NTDSAPI.dll
0x73560000 - 0x73572000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x73240000 - 0x7324d000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x75d30000 - 0x75d4b000     C:\Windows\system32\SspiCli.dll
0x75560000 - 0x75568000     C:\Windows\system32\credssp.dll
0x75800000 - 0x75842000     C:\Windows\system32\msv1_0.DLL
0x75ac0000 - 0x75ad1000     C:\Windows\system32\cryptdll.dll
0x756b0000 - 0x756ea000     C:\Windows\system32\schannel.DLL
0x75d10000 - 0x75d18000     C:\Windows\system32\secur32.dll
0x75a00000 - 0x75a38000     C:\Windows\system32\ncrypt.dll
0x759e0000 - 0x759f7000     C:\Windows\system32\bcrypt.dll
0x75580000 - 0x755bd000     C:\Windows\system32\bcryptprimitives.dll
0x75450000 - 0x75466000     C:\Windows\system32\GPAPI.dll
0x631e0000 - 0x63272000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexide.amt_4.6.0.328916\os\win32\x86\updaternotifications.dll
0x74490000 - 0x744a1000     C:\Windows\system32\NETAPI32.dll
0x75630000 - 0x75639000     C:\Windows\system32\netutils.dll
0x75ca0000 - 0x75cb9000     C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
0x74480000 - 0x7448f000     C:\Windows\system32\wkscli.dll
0x73a80000 - 0x73afd000     C:\Windows\system32\taskschd.dll
0x56280000 - 0x5628b000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexide.nativelibs_4.6.0.328916\os\win32\x86\Headlights.dll
0x6d000000 - 0x6d14a000     C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x6f7c0000 - 0x6f811000     C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x74060000 - 0x74065000     C:\Windows\system32\msimg32.dll
0x6e180000 - 0x6e2ef000     C:\Windows\system32\explorerframe.dll
0x74b70000 - 0x74b9f000     C:\Windows\system32\DUser.dll
0x74ab0000 - 0x74b62000     C:\Windows\system32\DUI70.dll
0x73900000 - 0x7390f000     C:\Users\*******\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\cascaded\328916\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\238\1\.cp\jWinHttp-1.0.0.dll
0x745f0000 - 0x7461e000     C:\Windows\system32\mlang.dll
0x6c2b0000 - 0x6c320000     C:\Windows\system32\ntshrui.dll
0x6f390000 - 0x6f39b000     C:\Windows\system32\cscapi.dll
0x739c0000 - 0x739ca000     C:\Windows\system32\slc.dll
0x6e680000 - 0x6e68d000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseStub32.dll
0x6e020000 - 0x6e08b000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseSVN32.dll
0x6dd30000 - 0x6e020000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libsvn_tsvn32.dll
0x6dd00000 - 0x6dd24000     C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\libapr_tsvn32.dll
0x6dc40000 - 0x6dcff000     C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=64m -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=eclipse/dropins -Declipse.application=com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.FlashBuilderApplication -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31
PATH=C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/jre/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin;c:\maven\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\dev\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\OpenView\service desk 4.5\client\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
USERNAME=*******
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1

Memory: 4k page, physical 2097151k(1385984k free), swap 4194303k(3980584k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (14.2-b01) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_16-b01), built on Jul 31 2009 11:26:58 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1

time: Tue Oct 09 14:07:53 2012
elapsed time: 3068 seconds
```

All this leads me to conclude that there must be something wrong with my **Xms/Xmx/MaxPermsize/PermSize** params.

I know that augmenting **Xmx** to something higher than **1024m** will cause additional crashes/unwanted behaviour.

Does anyone have an idea what the ideal values should be?

Any pointers on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you've already tried fiddling with the memory parameters for the VM? (Xms, Xmx, PermSize...)

Comment: @RIAstar updated my question for extra clarity

Comment: Flash Builder 4.7 is in beta and comes in a 64-bit flavor.  This should allow you to allocate more memory to Flash Builder.  Perhaps you should try it and see if that solves your problem?

Comment: No can do, using a 32-bit system. Customer laptop policy :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on you Error log, I think you are using Windows 7 in your PC, and your PC's memory is about 2G, right?

**In a nutshell, Your PC is not enough for Flashbuilder.**

for the Erorr, you can refer this one:
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: request  bytes for . Out of
swap space?
Although it appears that an OutOfMemoryError is thrown this apparent exception is reported by the
HotSpot VM code when an allocation from the native heap failed and the native heap may be close to
exhaustion. The message indicates the size (in bytes) of the request that failed and also indicates what
the memory is required for. In some cases the reason will be shown but in most cases the reason will
be the name of a source module reporting the allocation failure.
If an OutOfMemoryError with this error is thrown it may require using utilities on the operating
system to diagnose the issue further. Examples of issues that may not be related to the application are
when the operating system is configured with insufficient swap space, or when there is another
process on the system that is consuming all memory resources. If neither of these issues is the cause
then it is possible that the application is failed due to native leak;  for example, application or library
code is continuously allocating memory but is not releasing it to the operating system

-- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jdk50-ts-guide-149808.pdf
(J2SE Troubleshooting and Diagnostic Guide)。

For you PC, I think you need to reduce the Xmx , or close needless applictions.

Here is a example from Eclipse wiki:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

```
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Comment: Using Windows 7 is correct, however 4G of memory available on the machine.

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest the following similar questions
[Eclipse memory settings when getting "Java Heap Space" and "Out of Memory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334102/eclipse-memory-settings-when-getting-java-heap-space-and-out-of-memory/9993926#9993926)

and this blog post

http://www.redcodelabs.com/2012/03/eclipse-speed-up-flashbuilder/

Comment: Hi @DennisJaamann can you tell which of the links fixed your problem? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Disabling 'Design Mode' works for me.

Found in Window>Enable Design Mode

Comment: That is quite an interesting idea since indeed sometimes I get some error messages for null pointers occuring in design mode. Never use that feature anyway.