# Memory overflow Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I think that my Java Program exceeded the usage of memory allowed... this is the error that shows up in Eclipse:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at Main.main(Main.java:228)
```

before than trying an implementation with better memory handling, is there any way basically to augment the memory to allocate for the program ? I would like to see the program terminating and showing the result at least.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increase heap size in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can increase heap size using the cmd-line flags

For example:

```
java -Xmx6g myprogram
```

You can get a full list (or a nearly full list, anyway) by typing java -X.

Answer (score 1):

You can allocate more memory to the process by using the `-Xmx` flag:

```
java -Xmx2G YourProgram
```

Will allocate 2 Gigabytes of memory to the process.

You can do this in Eclipse by going to **Run Configurations**, the **Arguments** section and adding `-Xmx 2G` to the **VM arguments**.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing memory size is good, but you should also consider that probably your program has some memory leak and you really should bother about it.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't think your program is using that much memory, I suspect your program is having a memory leak somewhere.
If you could give `Main.java:200` till `Main.java:250` we could check for any leaks.

If you are sure your program is using that amount of memory you can either run
`java -Xmx2G -jar foo.jar` in the Command Prompt (Windows) or Terminal (Mac OS X or Linux) 
or, if you're running your program in Eclipse under Linux, do the following:

1) Make sure Eclipse is closed
2) Open your favorite text editor at your `eclipse.ini` file (Default location: `/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse.ini`)
3) Search for `--Xmx512M` and increase this number (i.e. `--Xmx2G`)
4) Save the file and restart Eclipse

For any explaination about `--Xmx` and `--Xms` I refer to [Eclipse memory settings when getting "Java Heap Space" and "Out of Memory"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/334102/4141219)

Happy coding :) -Charlie

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I am running a Ford Fulkerson algorithm to find a max flow in a directed graph. The graph is represented as a matrix adjecency .. and I suspect that its size can be like 17 000 * 17 000 ))

Comment: @FrancescoMarra If you're using a large algorithm (like you do) you can expect memory issues. Follow the steps I (and others) have written down to increase the `Java Heap Space`.