# Heap size in eclipse: what is it and what values are common?

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse i see I have 214M of 884M heap size but changes to 46M of 938M later

What exactly is this heap and what is it used for?

When I Google for it all I find is questions about how to enlarge it.... Which also makes me wonder if my max of 884M is sufficient?

The projects I develop aren't that big (11 java files)

Comment: Hope this might help https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: @TabrejKhan : Thanks. I read that page as well, but it doesn't explain what the heap size exactly is and what it is used for. Just that you can increase its maximum and how to do it.

Comment: Following link might be irrelevant but the answer has some good links to start with. One can get idea what exactly -X -XX means with respect to VM. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334102/eclipse-memory-settings-when-getting-java-heap-space-and-out-of-memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heap is the memory structure the Java Virtual Machine uses to hold objects, in this case the JVM that is running Eclipse (including the caches, etc.).

Here is an in-depth article that should help you understand it better (skim to "Memory Model"):
https://anturis.com/blog/java-virtual-machine-the-essential-guide/