# manage assigned memory size in Anylogic

Tags: jvm, anylogic, java-heap

for increasing the heap size for Anylogic I have followed the method explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56941311/how-do-i-increase-java-heap-size-for-anylogic) but it just work for 1.5G of ram. my operating system is Windows 10 (64bit) and JVM is 1.8.0_281 (64bit).
when I change the AnyLogic.ini file manually (for example changing -Xmx to 2048M), and try to run Anylogic, I face this error: "fail to create java virtual machine".

I would be appreciate if you help me to solve this problem, because it's essential.

Comment: What edition and version of AnyLogic are you using? The default memory is 4GB for the latest 8.7.2 version anyway (both Professional and PLE). Note that this memory setting is only for the AnyLogic client itself, not for executing models (which is specified per model experiment) --- you don't normally need to change it unless you have *very* large models.

Comment: Also note that your installed Java version is irrelevant since the AnyLogic client includes its own Java Runtime Environment (JRE).

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the ".AnyLogicProfessional" folder in your Windows home folder. Depending on your version, it could also be named ".AnyLogicUniversity" or similar.

Note: you must change the folder view options in Windows to see hidden folders.

Restart AnyLogic after that and it should work.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't worked. the same problem.