# Eclipse and Maven: JDK error

Tags: eclipse, maven

what do I need to write in my eclipse.ini to get rid of this warning:

> The Maven Integration requires that Eclipse be running in a JDK,
>   beacuase a number of Maven core plugins are using jars from the JDK.
>
> Please make sure the -vm options in eclipse.ini is pointing to a JDK
>   and verify that Installed JREs are also using JDK installs.

My ini says this and the problem is not solved:

```
 -startup
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar

 --launcher.library
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
 -showsplash org.eclipse.platform
 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m
 --launcher.defaultAction openFile
 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
 --launcher.defaultAction openFile
 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256M
 -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\javaw.exe
 -vmargs
 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
 -Xms40m
 -Xmx384m
```

Update: The above definitely doesn't change my vm I checked it according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557169/find-out-what-jvm-eclipse-is-running-on) and it says I'm still running `eclipse.vm=C:\Windows\System32\javaw.exe`

Update2: A suggested on several websites I tried to run eclipse from the commandline as  `.\eclipse -vm "..\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\javaw.exe"` and it worked!!! In "Eclipse Installation Details"->"Configuration" it now says `eclipse.vm=C:\Program Files\eclipse\\..\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\javaw.exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using slashes instead of backslashes for the folder of your jdk?

Comment: @tjb Then the only remaining difference to my ini file is, that my -vm arg is after launcher.library and not as late as in your ini

Comment: @tjb ... and my one does not contain a space character

Answer (score 2):

As has been suggested in other answers you should both change backslashes to forward slashes in your JDK path and put `-vm` and the JDK path on different lines. This is what works for me:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin/javaw.exe
```

I have these two lines as the first ones in my `eclipse.ini` file, but that should not be required.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my eclipse.ini (eclipse 3.6) and maven works fine

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
```

I just downloaded eclipse from official site, download maven 2.2.1 from apache site, installed

m2eclipse - http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e

m2eclipse Extras http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-extras

(Install new software)

Set up my maven installation in Window->Preferences->Maven->Installations

and that's all for me to work with maven.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an enter between -vm and the java path? I think it needs a new line. You can also try pointing to the jvm.dll instead of the .exe