# Eclipse not working - missing Java

Tags: eclipse

I downloaded the newest version of the SDK for android last night.  I also downloaded the standalone java (jr7 I think) as well.  I installed both, but it continually tells me that it cannot find the java.  So then I change the .ini file to tell it where JAVA was, but then it tells me it is missing the jvm.dll (I am going by memory), even though that files is clearly there.
Running Win 7, 64 bit.
So right now I can't even start this up or use it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic. You may want to try http://superuser.com.

Comment: is the java folder added to the system path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557169/find-out-what-jvm-eclipse-is-running-on

Comment: Can you paste the eclipse.ini you are using and the path to your installed java?

Comment: @SathishJayapal, that assumes he could get into eclipse in the first place, but this question indicates he cannot even start eclipse.

Comment: @Lucas care to provide an answer instead of searching issues in current answers?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I am trying to get more information.  My questions to the posted answers below are true curiosity.  Perhaps I misunderstand how eclipse works and if their answers could resolve this, i would like to know that.  I don't mean offense by it.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you downloaded the java runtime environment rather than the JDK.

Download the jdk from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Comment: Wouldn't eclipse still start up and just be unable to compile?  Also, his message said missing jvm.dll, jre should contain jvm.dll, no?

Comment: Even with just the jre, Eclipse would still be able to compile with its own JRE.  He mentioned android and most other java plugins (such as maven) require the jdk when Eclipse doesn't which pointed me towards it being the JDK installed but not the JRE, I could be wrong but it seemed pretty plausible.

Comment: I actually downloaded both the other day and installed them and neither worked.  I was going from memory so that is why I didn't mention it.  I have the JDK and the JRE as well installed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable. But before that we have to download the JDK, not JRE. These two are different. One is the Development Kit; the other is the Runtime Environment.

1. Right-click the My Computer icon on your desktop and select
   Properties.
2. Click the Advanced tab.
3. Click the Environment Variables button.
4. Under System Variables, click New.
5. Enter the variable name as JAVA_HOME.
6. Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit.
7. Click OK. Click Apply Changes.

Hopefully that should now point to your Java JDK location.

Comment: Would this help?  He said he tried setting the java location in his eclipse.ini.  That would override this value anyway...

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you.  Eclipse seems to find it now.  Going to have to play with it a while to be sure.

Comment: No problems. Glad everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you misconfigured your `eclipse.ini`.  I find it better practice to use `JAVA_HOME` as mentioned by @blackpanther any way.  I would suggest removing your edit to `eclipse.ini` and setting `JAVA_HOME`.  Make sure that `JAVA_HOME` specifies the root of your JDK: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.x_xx` (assuming windows).