# Incompatible magic value 0

Tags: java, maven

I'm developing java maven project in STS (based on Eclipse Juno 3.8.2) and I'm getting following error:

> java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 0 in class file org/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit4/runner/JUnit4TestReference

I think it have something to do with mixed Java versions, but I'm not able to solve it, probably I missed something.

Full stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 0 in class file org/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit4/runner/JUnit4TestReference
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

relenavt part of `pom.xml` is:

```xml
<plugin>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

my java version is:

```
> java -version
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and in Eclipse (STS) configuration for project is

[image: Eclipse Java Compiler Settings]

Maven dependencies:

```xml
<properties>
    <wicket.version>6.6.0</wicket.version>
    <jetty.version>7.6.3.v20120416</jetty.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Wicket -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- LOGGING DEPENDENCIES - LOG4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.javaconfig</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-javaconfig</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.m3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>c:\JavaLibs\hsqldb-2.2.9\hsqldb.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JETTY DEPENDENCIES FOR TESTING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I found out, that there is a problem only when I'm trying to run JUnit tests, my project is running fine. I tried to check run configuration and it seems it's ok. I checked project facets too, and everything seems to be ok there too...

Comment: I've googled and haven't gotten a clear answer as to "why" this happens, but it seems like the solution is to clean and regenerate your class files.  Since it seems to be happening in your library, perhaps you have a corrupted library?

Comment: Include in your question, the full list of Maven dependencies. Also, are you running tests via the Eclipse run menu when this error occurs, or executing a Maven goal?

Comment: I added maven dependencies, I'm running it via Eclipse run menu...

Comment: @tieTYT clean + build is first thing I'm trying in such cases and it din't help.

> Since it seems to be happening in your library, perhaps you have a corrupted library?

Excuse me, but why do you think it's somewhere in my corrupted library? In stack there are just `java`, `sun`, `org.eclipse` stackframes...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does this persist if you change the source and target versions to 1.7 in the POM?

Comment: That's something I didn't try yet. I'll give it a chance and let you know...

Comment: I changed java version in pom (for maven-compiler-plugin), installed JRE and Java compiler settings, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Despite having 1.7.0_17 on the command line I think your Eclipse is running on an older version of java. To determine what version of java Eclipse is running on see:

[Find out what JVM Eclipse is running on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557169/find-out-what-jvm-eclipse-is-running-on)

Then to change the version of java Eclipse is running on see:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but there are expected values in "Installation Details" `-vm C:\Programs\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll`,  `eclipse.vm=C:\Programs\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll`. I have only one JDK in my system.

Comment: I followed the above instruction and did find out that the JRE in Eclipse did point to 1.7 whereas others are pointing to 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that is some general problem with STS (based on Eclipse Juno 3.8.2).

I tried the simplest possible test and it's not working too:

## pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.betlista</groupId>
    <artifactId>tests-sts</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

## test class

```
package net.betlista.tests.sts.junit;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration( classes = { JavaConfig.class } )
public class CalculatorTest {

    @Autowired
    Calculator calculator;

    @Test
    public void addTest() {
        final int a = 10, b = 20;
        Assert.assertEquals( a + b, this.calculator.add( a, b ) );
    }

}
```

## configuration class

```
package net.betlista.tests.sts.junit;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class JavaConfig {

    @Bean
    public Calculator getCalculator() {
        return new Calculator();
    }

}
```

## service class

```
package net.betlista.tests.sts.junit;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Calculator {

    int add( final int a, final int b ) {
        return a + b;
    }

}
```

and I'm getting same error in STS (3.8.2), while in STS (4.2.2) everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

same here solved by simply **clean and rebuild the project** again

in my case this error happened just when i change a super class of the mentioned class;

the class mentioned on my stacktrace is a class in my project not in specific library like yours

`org/eclipse/jdt/internal/junit4/runner/JUnit4TestReference`

hope that help you

Answer (score 0):

I got this error messages but nothing worked for me. My problem probably is related to the way I move new classes from dev to production. I created the new class on Dev and copied it over to Production, not the .war file, at the end the class owner on tomcat folder was "root", not "tomcat", "chown" to tomcat fixed the problem.