# Eclipse issue with Maven build and JDK when generating Qclasses in Querydsl

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, querydsl

When I add this code below in my `pom.xml` to support **Querydsl**

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution> 
      <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I got this error when building with Eclipse. I think it has relation with classpath and JDK jars

```
You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on the classpath.
If this occures during eclipse build make sure you run eclipse under  JDK as well 
(com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.0.6:process:default:generate-sources)
```

**.classpath** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.runtimeTarget/Apache Tomcat v8.0">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Extra info :

[image]

My maven Installation

[image]

**JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45**
**PATH : %JAVA_HOME%\bin;**

Comment: How are you running the Maven build for this project? In eclipse or on the command  line?

Comment: I don't run Maven build i just use eclipse and when i add the code in my question to **pom.xml** i got the error.

Comment: If you go to `Windows > Preference > Maven > Installations`, what entries do you have there? Also, what does your `.classpath` look like?

Comment: Is this working when you run it outside Eclipse, or is this an eclipse-only issue?

Comment: @eis I work just with eclipse.

Comment: @Haricha I updated your question accordingly, since this seems to be Eclipse issue, not an issue with Spring or Maven as such

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1**

Following this [link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/126292-issues-with-querydsl-and-maven-pom-in-eclipse)

> "The Maven APT plugin has a known issue that prevents its usage
>   directly from Eclipse. Eclipse users must create the Querydsl query
>   types manually by running the command mvn generate-sources at command
>   prompt."

So i execute the command line `mvn generate-sources` in my project floder with console `cmd` and i got my Qclasses generated.

**SOLUTION 2** from @informatik01 comment

we can explicitly [specified JVM](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) in the `eclipse.ini` like that :

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe

-vmargs
...
```

The `-vm` option must occur before the `-vmargs` option and for more info read @informatik01 comment below.

Comment: I've gone to the project directory, I've run mvn generate-sources, I've set the Eclipse JDK version, but in Eclipse I still can't get my Q classes recognized. When I run the project with maven it works, but Eclipse gives me syntax errors in my code when I'm just looking at it. The sources are being generated in target/generate-sources . Is this the problem?

Comment: You have to add target/generate-sources/querydsl as a source folder.  Nothing in the target dir is considered source by default.

Comment: @MichaelTontchev http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26833880/including-qclasses-in-the-classpath

Comment: Few more pointers:- As solutions 2 didn't work for me initially
1. Make sure eclipse is 64 bit if you are using 64 bit JDK.
2. You might have to do a eclipse clean build after restarting eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

You could try with this in the pom:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution> 
      <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
      <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

And see if it changes anything. It should force tools.jar in the build path.

---

Edit. since that didn't help, try specifying

```
-vm 
D:/work/Java/jdk1.6.0_13/bin/javaw.exe
```

in eclipse.ini (separate lines are important), as explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905611/how-do-i-set-eclipse-ini-vm-option).

Comment: I try it but still got the same error i think the problem is in `You need to run build with JDK` not in `tools.jar` part

Comment: @Haricha they should be alternatives for each other. You'd need to either run the build with JDK or have tools.jar in the path. However, if that's not working for you, you could still try to tweak Eclipse startup options. That's explained in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905611/how-do-i-set-eclipse-ini-vm-option)

Comment: did you try the vm option?

Comment: yes of course, I solve it by generate the source in commande line `mvn generate-sources`

Comment: @eis You are right about your suggestion in your edit. See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482259/eclipse-issue-with-maven-build-and-jdk-when-generating-qclasses-in-querydsl#comment46070389_24513324)

Comment: I think with `/` int the path it didn't work with me. now with `\ ` it works

Answer (score 3):

I did it finally! I've tried so many option like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27619304/you-need-to-run-build-with-jdk-or-have-tools-jar-on-the-classpath) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482259/eclipse-issue-with-maven-build-and-jdk-when-generating-qclasses-in-querydsl), but no luck. Then I read this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710279/querydsl-maven-you-need-to-run-build-with-jdk-or-have-tools-jar-on-the-classpath/57397400#57397400) that saved my life, really, thank you! I follow this solution and its working suddenly! should be accepted answer in my case.

> I copied tools.jar from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\lib to C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib, after i execute mvn clean install – @julio mulcue burbano

Answer (score 1):

```
<groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>process</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JAPAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

add the plugin ,you will solve it

Answer (score 1):

This issue was happening to me because as mentioned above, Eclipse itself was running through the JRE instead of the JDK.

I solved it by adding **%JAVA_HOME%\bin** to the front of my PATH environment variable.

I figured out what JVM eclipse was using by reading through: [Find out what JVM Eclipse is running on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557169/find-out-what-jvm-eclipse-is-running-on)

Answer (score 0):

If you build by shell commond like mvn install. Then run this command in the shell or cmd window: echo $CLASSPATH. This command shows your classpath.

If you are using Eclipse, open Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs, make sure your installed JREs are of jdk root location. For me, it is  C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_51

Hope it helps.

Comment: it didn't work i update my question with extra info.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the JDK in Eclipse as below:

set the JRE in

look at the path below - having `program files`(but in your mentioned path it is not having  `program files` in your path , usually java and all programs gets install in `program files` so make sure that path)

```
 Window->Preferences...->Java->Installed JREs:

JRE type: Standard VM JRE 
Name: jdk1.6.0_18
JRE home directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_18
```

alos make sure `JAVA_HOME` path is set properly to `JDK\bin` properly(without any spaces and all in that path)

Try copying your `JDK` to a different location and update your `JAVA_HOME` with that new location.

let me know for any other issues.

Comment: it didn't works, i update my question with extra info.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check the setting of the **Execution Environment** in in your Eclipse Project Settings: **Project Build Path -> Libraries -> JRE System Library**.

If this is wrong (e.g. **jre**), switch this to a **jdk** one.

In my case, this solved the issue ("You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on the classpath." disappeared).

Then the approx. fourth line in the Maven Run Log changes from (e.g.)

```
...
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66
....
```

to

```
 ...
 Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre
 ...
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had done everything suggested above but to no avail. Finally, because I was setting up a new computer, I realized I didn't have a `JAVA_HOME` variable set up.

So all I did was to add the `JAVA_HOME` variable to my system variables and set that to a JDK path: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172`

And voila - `mvn generate-resources` started working again.