# QueryDSL-maven-You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on the classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, querydsl

I have same question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482259/eclipse-issue-with-maven-build-and-jdk-when-generating-qclasses-in-querydsl),and I have tried the two solutions,but none works for me.

I copied the configuration for querydsl from it's [github](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/tree/master/querydsl-jpa) page .

So my querydsl maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And my apt configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                    <version>4.1.4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
      </plugin>
```

I also modified eclipse.ini,add follow at first line:

```
-vm
D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\javaw.exe
```

But I till get the same error in eclipse:

```
You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on the classpath.If this occures during eclipse build make sure you run eclipse under JDK as well (com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3:process:default:generate-sources)
```

And when I run `mvn genarate-sources` in cmd,same error occurs:

```
[INFO] --- apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3:process (default) 
[ERROR] execute error
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on the classpath.If this occures during eclipse build make sure you run eclipse under JDK as well
```

Any one can help me?

Comment: I copied **tools.jar** from `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\lib` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib`, after i execute mvn clean install

Answer (score 2):

Please include the following line in your `eclipse.ini` or `STS.ini` in case of STS,

`-vm
{path_to_jdk}\jdk{your_version}\bin\javaw.exe`

For more information [issue](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/issues/247)

Comment: The -vm option must occur before the -vmargs option

Answer (score 1):

finally,I solved this.The reason is that I have JDK1.7 and JDK1.8 both installed on my computer,when I run `java -version` in cmd,it gots error bellow:

```
 Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion' has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required
```

I removed both 1.7 and 1.8,reinstall 1.8 and evertything is fine.I got QClass genarated.

So stupid i am...

Answer (score 1):

I did it finally! I've tried so many option like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27619304/you-need-to-run-build-with-jdk-or-have-tools-jar-on-the-classpath) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482259/eclipse-issue-with-maven-build-and-jdk-when-generating-qclasses-in-querydsl), but no luck. Then I read this comment that saved my life, really, thank you! I follow this solution and its working suddenly! should be accepted answer in my case.

> I copied tools.jar from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\lib to C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib, after i execute mvn clean install – @julio mulcue burbano

Comment: I tried with .ini file changes it didn't work.. Finally your solutions worked . Thanks.