# Spring Tool Suite issue with Maven build and JDK when generating Qclasses in Querydsl

Tags: spring, maven, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to generate QClasses for Spring Data MongoDb using QueryDSL

following the spring documentation, my plugin entry in pom.xml looks like this

```
<plugin>    
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                   <execution>
                        <id>process-common-model</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/apt</outputDirectory>
                            <processors>
                                <processor>
                                  org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoAnnotationProcessor
                                </processor>
                            </processors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                 </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I get the following error on the execution element

**You need to run build with JDK or have tools.jar on the classpath.If this occures during eclipse build make sure you run eclipse under JDK as well (com.mysema.maven:apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3:process:process-common-model:generate-sources)**

I have tried to look this up on online and what I understand that is that sts run under installed JRE which is missing tools.jar for this execution. So folks have suggested to change the vm options in sts.ini like this:

-vm
D:\jde\jdks\jdk1.6.0_37\bin\javaw.exe

Relevant online links are:

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/126292-issues-with-querydsl-and-maven-pom-in-eclipse

[Eclipse issue with Maven build and JDK when generating Qclasses in Querydsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482259/eclipse-issue-with-maven-build-and-jdk-when-generating-qclasses-in-querydsl)

I fail to find sts.ini or any such file where vm options can be changed is. I am running STS on a windows machine. I could find STS configuration setting files which looks exactly the same as eclipse.ini based on its contents. So I added -vm options in it and now this file looks like this

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javaw.exe-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms40m
-Dosgi.module.lock.timeout=10
-Xverify:none
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Xmx1200m
```

Modifying this file also doesn't resolve this issue.

Can anyone tell me how to go about this issue ? I have been stuck on this the whole day.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the documentation about the eclipse.ini file (the sts.ini file is the same but for STS):

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

According to this documentation, you have to put "-vm" on the first line of your ini file, and the path to the javaw.exe on the second line. On the third line, the rest of the ini file starts (with the "-startup" line).

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I read all that. However, I don't see a .ini in sts for windows.

Comment: Can you double check whether the sts.ini file was included in the STS distro ZIP file that you downloaded and extracted?