# How do I change my Eclipse IDE's launch JVM?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jvm, eclipse-oxygen

I'm running Eclipse Oxygen (1A) on my Mac and I can see in the "Installation Details" that the JVM currently being used by the IDE itself (to actually launch the JVM) is Oracle's `1.8.0_131` JVM. I have a few other JVMs installed including the latest release `1.8.0_161` and I'd like to switch to the latest.

Just to be clear: I'm not trying to set the execution environment which is used when compiling and/or launching code *for a particular project*. I'm trying to change the JVM which is used when launching Eclipse itself.

So far, I've made sure that Eclipse is aware of my updated JRE and that it is indeed the default "Installed JRE", but restarting Eclipse ends up using the same, old, JVM (1.8.0_131).

Is there a way to tell Eclipse that I'd like to use an updated JVM without editing the Eclipse launch scripts directly? (I'm assuming I could do that if I wanted to, but I'd prefer not to do so.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557169/find-out-what-jvm-eclipse-is-running-on

Comment: Editing the eclipse.ini is the way this is done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [reference documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) we learn (basic) details on how the Eclipse launcher executable looks for suitable Java installations:

> `-vm`  (Executable, Main)
>
> when passed to the Eclipse executable, this option is used to locate the Java VM to use to run Eclipse. It should be the full file system path to an appropriate: Java `jre/bin` directory, Java Executable, Java shared library (jvm.dll or libjvm.so), or a Java VM Execution Environment description file.
>
> **If not** specified, the Eclipse executable uses **a search algorithm** to locate a suitable VM. In any event, the executable then passes the path to the actual VM used to Java Main using the -vm argument. Java Main then stores this value in eclipse.vm.

Sadly, the result of that "*search algorithm*" is not explicitly specified which somehow makes it "a bit" non-deterministic. Even more complicating: It might be a strategy which is platform dependent.

*EDIT*: In the section [Eclipse Launcher](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Flauncher.html) the algorithm is explained better, providing more details.

> When **no** `-vm` is specified, the launcher looks for a virtual machine *first* in a **jre directory** in the **root of eclipse** and then on the **search path**.

Given the above "jvm search" process and (the related) implications, you can (only) have a stable environment by specifying a path via `-vm` in `eclipse.ini`. This should point to the "stable" path as returned by the command `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`*.

*Note: Simply, check the result of this command via a *Terminal* locally.

In my MacOS environment the above command results in:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

As you can see in the next listing, I created a symlink which points to the actual and up2date JDK as installed on in my system.

```
node:JavaVirtualMachines user$ ls -lah
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  wheel   192B 18 Jan 13:35 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel   160B  6 Okt 14:28 ..
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    17B 18 Jan 13:34 1.8.0.jdk -> jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    14B  3 Nov 10:42 1.9.0.jdk -> jdk-9.0.1.jdk/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    96B  3 Nov 10:40 jdk-9.0.1.jdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    96B 18 Jan 13:32 jdk1.8.0_161.jdk
```

Investigating your question further, I came along with an interesting observation in my local Eclipse Oxygen.2 installation which might also apply in your case. In the below screenshot we see, that the JRE **name** is somehow "static" and not updated with new versions.

[image: JRE name mismatch]

Verify your local situation by clicking the "Edit..." button in the Installed JRE list. It might actually point to an up2date JRE/JDK version. In the best case you just have to adjust the name of this entry.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oddly enough, my `eclipse.ini` says `-vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin` and yet the running Eclipse says it's running `jdk1.8.0_122` instead. Seems I did an end-run around this long ago where I symlinked the new JRE's installation directory to the old name.

Comment: I opted to remove the `-vm` argument (and parameter) entirely from `eclipse.ini` (by using leading `#` signs in `eclipse.ini`) and a restart caused Eclipse to use the latest JRE available. I think I'll keep this configuration so I always get the latest.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. Keep in mind, however, that you might run into version „trouble“ (again) if both JDK8 and 9 would be installed on your system at the same time: The environment decides which JDK you will be using. I hope my answer helped to clarify the situation and gives you a direction, i.e., it provides you the options on the table.

Answer (score 6):

You need go in the folder of eclipse , open eclipse.ini and add this line :

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_7/bin/javaw.exe
```

Change path whit your java path

Comment: Please note that the OP references a JVM in version `1.8+`. How can your proposed solution be correct, when it refers a JDK in version `1.7`? It might not even be installed on this machine as it is rather outdated...

Comment: Also, I have no `C:` drive on my Mac ;)

Comment: @MWiesner did you miss the "Change path whit your java path" part of this answer?