# Eclipse is unable to open, have used eclipse before and has open before without a problem. Now I keep getting the following error message:

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:

Have gotten eclipse to open and work on projects before and won't open.

Here is a screen shot of what I keep getting:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5kOC.png)

Comment: If you are able, please copy the entire text of the error message, and paste it into the question.  (I used "If you are able" because I've seen some error message displays that did not permit copying the text.)

Comment: Java on your machine might have been uninstalled or deleted. Have you explored to see what is in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1`  ? If you don't have 18.0~, is there another JDK on your machine?

Comment: If you have the JRE installed somewhere other than the directory specified in the message, then you may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48349760) helpful.

Comment: What version of Eclipse? Old versions might not understand Java 18. Most downloads of the current version of Eclipse (2022-12) contain a suitable Java packaged with the download.

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example

Comment: Have any updates been run?  Whether manual or automatic, was Java recently updated? Was Eclipse recently updated?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have uninstalled the jdk ,try installing the jdk again,set the environment variables. It should work

Comment: jdk are already installed and path is aslo set even after that i get this error