# Why is the Eclipse IDE getting slower?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I have downloaded the latest Eclipse IDE, Galileo, and tested it to see if it good for developing web applications in Java. I have also tried the Ganymede version of Eclipse and find that is it also good.

My Problem is that sometimes it hangs and stops responding while I am developing. Sometimes when I open a file, Eclipse hangs and does not respond for awhile. It seems that Eclipse is going slower and my job is getting slower because of the time that I am spending waiting for the response of Eclipse.

When I went to NetBeans 6.7, it was good and the performance was good. The loading is faster and the IDE responds well during my development testing.

My computer has 1 GB of RAM and a 1.6 GHz CPU.

What can you say about this?

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse, especially http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-eclipse-34-jvm-settings#144349 ?

Comment: Didn't see that questions but I have tried it and saw it in other references, It gave some speed up but at some point it still goes slow.

Comment: Yes, but my "eclipse.ini" is quite optimized now and should avoid any degradation of speed. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried it, and the loading of eclipse gets faster now and also its response time. Hope it will still be on the same speed while developing.

Comment: I ran Galileo on a 1.7GHz Celeron with 512MB RAM (2006). It was slow because of the constant disk swapping, I added a readyboost SD-card, but the real improvement came when I maxed out the RAM to 2GB. Other than that, Eclipse is fast and more responsive than ever.

Comment: Is your trade to write software? If so, why are you using an incredibly old and underpowered machine? Computers are cheap, and I think you would find at today's rates, you would recoup the cost of a new machine in time very quickly.

Comment: @wsorenson : try to have your boss, who only uses word and excel, to understand that $20 for 1GB of RAM (I suppose that's appropriate -- not using dollars in France ^^ ) would allow you to gain somthing like ONE ENTIRE DAY of work each month (if you spend 25 minutes waiting each day, 20 days per month...)... Un-happilly some people don't understand that :-( (same with more powerful computer, better screen, or even better chair, btw ^^ )

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN if you work for a company that has a problem spending $20 for 1GB of RAM for a s/w developer, you are in serious trouble.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm using Eclipse PDT 2.1 (also based on Galileo) for PHP development, and I've been using Eclipse-based IDE for 3 years now ; my observation is that 1 GB of RAM is generally not enough to run Eclipse + some kind of web server + DB server + browser + other stuff :-(

*I'm currently working with a 1GB of RAM machine, and it's slow as hell... Few months ago, I had a 2GB of RAM machine, and things were going really fine -- and I'm having less software running on the "new machine" than I had on the other one !*

Other things that seem to affect Eclipse's responsivness is :

- opening a project that's on a network drive (accessing the sources that are on a development server via samba, for instance)
- sometimes, using an SVN-plugin like SUbversive seems to freeze Eclipse for a couple of seconds/minutes

A nice to do with languages like PHP (might not be OK for JAVA projects, though) is to disable "automatically build" in "project"'s menu.

*As a sidenote : I've already seen questions about eclipse's speed on SO ; you might want to try so searches, to get answers faster ;-)*

Comment: What is SO? You're soaking in it! It's StackOverflow!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I used "SO" without thinking you might not have seen it used before ; It's a shorter way to write StackOverflow ^^

Comment: whoa! Sorry for not knowing that.. huh.. Oh.. It StackOverflow.. Thanks for the info. I'm still new here in SO. Thanks..

Comment: No problem ^^ (damn limit of at least 15 characters in a comment... )

Comment: Even on a machine with 24 GB, you can experience hangs if you have enough disk activity.  Make sure you have enough memory for your OS, your IDE, your applications and to keep all your project and workspace files in memory without touching the disk.

Comment: I have 16GB RAM + Core i7  8750H CPU, Eclipse is consuming almost 3GB of RAM, and this piece of sh%& still frozen everytime! What else could I possible need to run this program fine?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common concern and others have posted similar questions.  There are optimizations that you can perform on your Eclipse environment.  Take a look at the [solutions posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-eclipse-34-jvm-settings#144349).

Answer (score 0):

Our machines are bigger : 2GB ram, and faster CPU.

I'm sure that, as all software, Eclipse gets bigger and slower when upgrading version, due to all new functionnalities included. The good news is that from time to time, a release also brings some notable performance improvement. But in my experience, each time I tried using a ten-year old software on my current machine, it was lightning fast, so I'm sure the tendency is to get slower. I agree that this is a sad for us, when we don't get a better machine.

There might be some things you can do, to improve the responsiveness of your Eclipse.
I don't know if you already tried everything ... ?

Comment: I am not sure about the "getting slower with each version" thing. I don't know about JAVA, of course (I don't work in JAVA), but for PHP, getting new versions of Eclipse PDT often tends to get better performances ; it was the case when switching from PDT 1.x to PDT 2.x, at least ; and should be the case with switching from 2.1 to 2.2, if stuff that is planned to be integrated (new DLTK indexing, I believe) is indeed integrated

Comment: Newer versions are often better coded but bigger. The "bigger" part can hurt people with less RAM.

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been that NetBeans, Aptana, and Komodo are fast on computers where Eclipse is painfully slow. Maxing out RAM has seemed to help. Any chance you can bump up to 2 gig?

Comment: I hear the same.  But on the other hand, I hear that Eclipse can do a wider range of things that the other IDEs.

Comment: Yeah, Eclipse is huge and tons of plugs-ins. For a lot of jobs it's mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans sped up quite a bit in the last few years, perhaps your comparison is relative to the speed of netbeans?

Lately I had to up the size of my eclipse -Xmx from 64mb and decided I might as well go to 512, and it got a bit chunkier.  at 64 I never saw the slightest pause, when it actually NEEDS a collection at 512 because of a long-running process that's not letting the background GC thread run, it can get a little pausey

I'm running on a pretty old version of eclipse (customized by the cable industry so it can run and display cable apps on a TV emulator) so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

netbeans is really damn hot, i just didn get it to automatically release my android projects...

thinking of features.. i'd prefere eclipse...

**to fasten it up a little more, just disable 'automatic build' doesnt really change anything (build just takes a little longer)**

but it's really feelable faster...

but, after 1 or 2 hours, i also have to close, wait, and re-open it.

kind of sucks... (gotta macbook pro, 2.26 (i think) ghz, 3gb ram,
gave it a minimum of 768MB of ram, and keeps getting slower..

really sucks

::edit::
I also realized, that after opening a XML file, eclipse instantly gets a little bit more laggy (already disabled XML live compiling, or something similiar, makes no difference :( )

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can disable unwanted plugins during start up.

[image: Eclipse Startup Shutdown Settings]

Answer (score -1):

It has been 13 years since this thread was created and eclipse is still slow. They should just scrape this project, it keeps wasting time of thousands of developers everyday. For me it just never worked. RAM is not the issue. The real problem is the way they glue everything in their system which calls different services thus using network resources which slows down everything. then there are plugins.

Here is an interesting post ;) https://ajaytechie.com/eclipse/why-is-eclipse-so-fucking-slow.html