# MapForce vs. Talend Open Studio

Tags: etl

We have been using Talend 3.1 for a few months now. However, we are looking at possibly switching to the latest MapForce. Simply because it compiles to a .Net solution and we are otherwise a .Net house. That being said Talend is extremely easy to use and extend. The Talend jobs make it very easy for new developers to understand the job and modify existing issues. There does seem to be a general feeling of buggyness with Talend (eg slow responsiveness in the UI and some strange behavior).

If you have worked with one or both can I get your opinion on how they match up?

Thanks

Comment: The sluggishness in Talend Open Studio's UI is, of course, because it's based on Eclipse which is always slow, IMHO. There's another SO thread here with tips for speeding up Eclipse, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse

Otherwise, I am just starting to use Talend and am liking what I've found so far, even including how easy it is to extend. No experience with MapForce so I can't comment on that.

Answer (score 4):

With Talend's acquisition of Sopera, Talend now has a tight integration with an ESB product stack which is very light weight.  Among other things, the ESB includes a first class integration based on services implemented with .NET WCF.  So if you are looking to integrate data  / web services in .NET but enjoy the simplicity of the Talend UI (which can be slow because of Eclipse), then I would try the new product integration with Talend ASF / ESB.

Caveat, I am a Talend employee, but I hope this note is sufficiently objective and factual.

Comment: Hey Ed, I've just started looking into Talend as an alternative to BizTalk. Can you recommend any good sources of learning material? The Tutorials are a bit to unfocussed for me as i'm just starting out! thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to get Talend to consume WCF services. Which ever I tried, I have failed misserably

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use MapForce for integration work you will need the **FlowForce server** and **MapForce server** besides **MapForce**.

Minimally you could use **MapForce** and the **MapForce server**. Compile the Mapping to a **MapForce Server Execution File** and then run it with the tool of your choice.