# Eclipse 3.5 64-bit Performance Windows 7

Tags: windows, eclipse, performance, 64-bit

I installed Eclipse Galileo and after trouble with the JDK, its starting well. But I have big problems with performance. Every third second, Eclipse is hanging for a while. It runs not smoothly. I need a efficient IDE as Eclipse for work. So, it would be very nice when you have a fast answer :)

Both Eclipse as the JDK are 64-bit versions.

Have you any ideas?

**Update**:

I can´t really explain the problem from scratch. But in my case, it was a trouble between Eclipse´s and the auto-complete-function of my OSK. If I disabled auto-complete, there was no hangs anymore. I don't know why the using of the OSK blocks the thread (?) of the whole editor.

Maybe anyone of you, has an idea why?

Comment: Do you have any plug-ins installed? I've been running 64-bit Eclipse with 64-bit Java on Win7 since the beta without any performance issues. It might be related to your environment.

Comment: I have the same problem as well.  Especially when using the Android SDK.  It is very painful then.  I had to disable plugins just to stop it from freezing up in the code editor window.

Comment: Could you please let us know what is OSK??

Comment: @sarikan [On-screen keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_keyboard), in this case of Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can´t really explain the problem from scratch. But in my case, it was a trouble between Eclipse´s and the auto-complete-function of my OSK. If I disabled auto-complete, there was no hangs anymore. I don´t know why the using of the OSK blocks the thread (?) of the whole editor.

Maybe anyone of you, has an idea why?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

From your description it sounds like the garbage collector is being triggered. How much RAM have you got in the system? Depending on the plugins you're loading Eclipse can need quite a lot of it. I think the bare minimum is 256 Mb, and realistically you need at least 1 Gb, more if you're doing web development

Have you got an up-to-date JVM? Eclipse generally runs much quicker with a 1.6 JVM.

One other thing to check, do you have an aggressive virus scanner? Eclipse plugins are collections of small files in jars, some virus scanners can really slow down the performance. If you are able, remove the Eclipse install directory from the scanned files.

See this [EclipseZone article](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61618.html) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse) for some general performance tips.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer but I have 4 GB of RAM and I don´t think that the issue is because of my hardware. 
Yes im running a 1.6 JVM. The tip of an agressive virus scanner: Good idea, but I don´t use a scanner :)
I become to desperate!

Comment: Have you run through the items in the linked question? in particular check the eclipse.ini file, the -Xmx and -XX:MaxPermSize arguments may be set too low. Also can you list the additional plugins you have installed?

Comment: Yes I have run through. All argurments are high enough!

Comment: can you list the additional plugins you have installed? or is it a clean install?

Comment: It´s a clean install, yes.
When Eclipse is running and stumble, the window disappears very shortly from the task bar. It´s very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and see what kind of system calls and/or file system calls the JVM is doing. Use filters aggressively to pinpoint a specific process. I had a similar issue where a graphics card utility triggered a flood of registry lookups for every UI update which just made Eclipse incredibly slow. (Somehow SWT was hit exceptionally hard by this bug, I'm not sure why.)

EDIT: I meant "Process Monitor", not "Process Explorer". But the link was correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was able isolate my issue: When i wait for a few seconds I can click for example on "File -> New -> Java Project". All is running very smoothly! But instantly when I select code in the text editor Eclipse stumble and the javaw.exe blast up to 50 percent of CPU. So I don´t think it´s a UI issue, or?
Therefor I started Process Explorer, but I can´t find what you mean. Could you explain your advice further?

I hope it was understandable!

Comment: Process Monitor allows you to monitor everything which happens in Windows in real time (as it happens): files being written, registry accesses, thread creation etc. There is a huge amount of data available, but in order to make sense of it you need to filter the data so that it only displays the relevant data for your process. If you see some resource being hit hard (excessive registry access, for example), you can filter on that specific kind of access to see more details.

Comment: ...also, if you manage to pinpoint an exact name of a file or registry entry you'll want to google it to see if others have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to run it from within a virtual machine set up on your computer to see if the problem is still there. If it's not, it might be faster for you to just work from within the virtual machine environment. Doesn't address the issue, but it may help avoid it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for me

I have Windows 7 professional 64 bit and 8gb of RAM

Eclipse is extremely slow, probably 5 times slower than the Windows Vista 32 bit machine I have recently upgraded from (Europa version) - and that machine was a complete dog!

Adding -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseParallelGC -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll has made a pretty big difference

Comment: adding -Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseParallelGC
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll has made a pretty big difference.

Comment: Thanks Matt! You should add this comment as an answer. My Galileo on 64bit W7 is noticeably faster.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem so I just switched to the 32 bit version of Eclipse and it runs fine with no performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem as not respoinding. 
I searched in internet for a solution. I found one by adding the below to
eclipse helios config file.
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe

Initially it looks Ok to start and click on the different buttons and 
running on several files in eclips project. But when I click on debug
and step by step process. Then it is again showing not respoding. 
I have a new laptop win7 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problems with the 32 bit version, running with a 32 bit JVM.

It's more that my RCP Application which I developed with Eclipse is slow.  I've tried both -Xmx1024m and -XX:+UseParallelGC, with no noticable effect.  Has this issue been registed with eclipse.org?