# Android. How to improve Eclipse Performance for projects with lots of resources?

Tags: android, performance

I have notices following:

1. if I have a project with minimum files in res folder, the project saves quickly, compiles quickly and launches quickly.
2. But if I have a lot of resources, my project is saving, compiling and launching during relatively long period of time. This is really frustrating if you do some minor UI updates, and you have always wait Eclipse to generate R file etc.

Is there any recipe how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has to process all of the resource files, so naturally the more you have the longer it will take. You may be able to speed up all of Eclipse by following the tips in [How can you speed up Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse).