# Speedup IntelliJ-Idea

Tags: java, windows, performance, intellij-idea

I'm using intelliJ for Scala development and got *8 GB* of new RAM last week, so I thought: time to use it. I checked my task manager and found intelliJ using *~250mb*. From eclipse I knew that tweaking JVM options helped a lot in improving speed, so I googled ...

and found [this one for OS X](http://blog.amber.org/2010/12/intellij-idea-10-performance-on-mac-os-x/)
I couldn't find the JVM option immediately, so I started tweaking *Xmx.* At 1 GB, I realized it doesn't start any more. I checked the intelliJ java version, found it's outdated and 32bit.

So in order to use your current JDK and **64 bit** you have to change your link to from:

```
IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 10.0.2\bin\idea.exe
```

to

```
IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 10.0.2\bin\idea.BAT
```

and adjust "Start in"

The bat looks for `JDK_HOME` and uses 64bit now.

My current **VM Options**, which are located in

```
...\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 10.0.2\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions
```

are

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-ea
-server
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseParallelGC
```

Instead of `-XX:+UseParallelGC`, you can use `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`, which is

> the accepted choice for desktop apps,
>   but I have changed to the throughput
>   collector recently. because with a
>   fast machine and a small enough heap,
>   you have quick pauses, more throughput
>   and no issues with fragmentation
>   (ijuma. #scala)

Changes:

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC //removed
// removed, because not needed with the lastest JVM.
    -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
    -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
    -XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

I'll stick to these options for now. I would really like to know your experience with it.

**Which options work best for you?
How do I hide this cmd window while running intelliJ through the `.bat`? :)**

By the way, here's another link for [tuning intelliJ](http://www.slideshare.net/intelliyole/intellij-idea-architecture-and-performance). Basically it says on *p.20/21* to turn off windows restore and antivirus for system dirs.

Another way to speed up intelliJ is to put intellij system folder on **ramdrive** (thanks OlegYch|h).

```
from idea.properties 
idea.system.path=${idea.home}/.IntelliJIdea/system
```

See [Superuser for Win 7 64bit RAM Drive](https://superuser.com/questions/34388/whats-the-best-ramdisk-for-windows) or [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/76757/ram-drive-for-vista-win7-64bit).
1 GB seems fine for me.

Another hint a friend gave me is to **exclude the project directories from your antivirus** (scan on access)

There are similar posts regarding tuning Eclipse:

- [Eclipse Helios 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse)
- [Eclipse Juno 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149874/equivalent-jvm-options-with-oracle-j2se-1-7-for-eclipse-kepler-4-3)
- [Specify the JVM to start Eclipse with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/how-can-you-speed-up-eclipse/316535#316535)

Comment: If the 64 bit version is run, the VM options are going to be read from `idea64.exe.vmoptions`

Comment: I added a similar question, but for a 32-bit OS (Windows 7) and 3 GB RAM: [IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 - how to prevent low memory problems on a 32-bit OS (Win 7) with 3GB RAM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026291/intellij-idea-13-1-how-to-prevent-low-memory-problems-on-a-32-bit-os-win-7-w)

Comment: Why not run "idea64.exe" directly, instead of through the .bat file? (at least there is idea64.exe in IntelliJ idea 11?

Answer (score 35):

This combination works great on my Intellij13 running in Mavericks:

**Updated Jul 18, 2017**:

```
# custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options

-ea
-server
-Xms2G
-Xmx4096M
-Xss2m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2G
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1G
-XX:MetaspaceSize=512m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=256m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=8
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=60
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary
-XX:+UseSplitVerifier
-XX:CompileThreshold=10000
-XX:+OptimizeStringConcat
-XX:+UseStringCache
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd

-Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine
```

I keep this setting updated at https://github.com/adben/config/blob/master/idea64.vmoptions

Comment: you have plent of duplications in there

Comment: be careful with this one `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings` , out of all on your list, this broke it for me, the rest worked.

Comment: Thanks @adben, it's greatly improved IJ on my PC. But I had to remove `MaxMetaspaceSize`, `MetaspaceSize`, `UseCompressedStrings` because they are not supported in IJ 14 on linux x86_64. `UseCompressedOops` ddin't work for me either. Hint: run IJ from command line to see error messages, on linux it's `idea.sh`

Comment: -XX:+UseCompressedStrings broke it for me too on Win8 x64 and IDEA 64-bit version. Everything else seems okay.

Comment: To edit this file in the first place, simply press **Ctrl+Shift+A** for the Find Action popup and type "**Edit Custom VM Options**". It will automatically create the correct file for your machine that you can edit.

Comment: # -XX:+UseStringCache
# -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
# -XX:+UseSplitVerifier
These dont work with 2021 version.

Answer (score 31):

For me switching to SSD-drive improved performance a lot (especially for large projects).

Comment: I am definitely going to benchmark IJ performance with SSD and an HDD!

Answer (score 23):

Some time ago I was looking for the ways to speedup my project's compilation and that is result. This is not for IntelliJ IDEA itself but will help a lot when (re)building a big projects and, I guess, it will work with any other IDEs too. Also, I described Linux approach, but I'm sure Windows have it's own RAM-disk implementations.

The easiest way to speedup compilation is to move compilation output to RAM disk.

## RAM disk setup

#### Open fstab

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

(instead of `gedit` you can use `vi` or whatever you like)

#### Set up RAM disk mount point

I'm using RAM disks in several places in my system, and one of them is `/tmp`, so I'll just put my compile output there:

```
tmpfs /var/tmp tmpfs defaults 0 0
```

In this case your filesystem size will not be bounded, but it's ok, my `/tmp` size right now is 73MB. But if you afraid that RAM disk size will become too big - you can limit it's size, e.g.:

```
tmpfs /var/tmp tmpfs defaults,size=512M 0 0
```

## Project setup

In IntelliJ IDEA, open Project Structure (`Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S` by default), then go to Project - 'Project compiler output' and move it to RAM disk mount point:

```
/tmp/projectName/out
```

(I've added `projectName` folder in order to find it easily if I need to get there or will work with several projects at same time)

Then, go to Modules, and in all your modules go to Paths and select 'Inherit project compile output path' or, if you want to use custom compile output path, modify 'Output path' and 'Test output path' the way you did it to project compiler output before.

That's all, folks!

P.S. A few numbers: time of my current project compilation in different cases (approx):

```
HDD:     80s
SSD:     30s
SSD+RAM: 20s
```

P.P.S. If you use SSD disk, besides compilation speedup you will reduce write operations on your disk, so it will also help your SSD to live happily ever after ;)

Comment: Ram solution is great !! not only for performance but also protect SSD life time .thanks!

Comment: I moved my `caches` and `index`folders via symbolic link to a RAM disk, [Intellij IDEA cache in RAM Drive](http://sheroz.com/pages/blog/improving-development-performance-moving-intellij-idea-cache-ramdisk.html) suggests another way to do it without symbolic links, however it would require a larger RAM disk because you can't specify only the caches and index folders that way. Needless to say, any search/lookup/clicking a symbol is instant or almost-instant now

Comment: How to do this on windows 10?

Comment: @ycomp could you please elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: I can't remember specifically, but it's probably more trouble than it's worth. Although it was wicked fast. I can't remember if there were any specific problems associated with doing that.. I stopped doing it once I migrated to another PC

Comment: Here I've answered my own question on how I have achieved that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56579056/moving-intellij-idea-caches-index-directories-to-ram/56608390#56608390

Answer (score 20):

Regarding:

> How do I hide this cmd window while running intelliJ through the .bat?

Use the 'start' command and javaw.exe together, so, if you have:

```
SET JAVA_EXE=%IDEA_JDK%\jre\bin\java.exe
...
"%JAVA_EXE%" %JVM_ARGS% -cp "%CLASS_PATH%" %IDEA_MAIN_CLASS_NAME% %*
```

change it to:

```
SET JAVA_EXE=%IDEA_JDK%\jre\bin\javaw.exe
...
start "Intellij IDEA" /b "%JAVA_EXE%" %JVM_ARGS% -cp "%CLASS_PATH%" %IDEA_MAIN_CLASS_NAME% %*
```

Answer (score 19):

The most useful thing you can do for IntelliJ is to have a lot of *free memory for disk caching*.  IntelliJ saves alot of its processing work in cached files.  This works well if you have plenty of free memory, but if your disk cache is limited, you will see regular, long lasting pauses.

I would suggest `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` rather than `G1`.

I also work local copies of files to minimise file access delay.

*BTW*: For the project I am on, I noticed the difference between working on a machine with 24 GB and one with 48 GB, even though the max heap is set to 2 GB ;)

Comment: For me, the most important realisation is that when it pauses, its not due to GC, but rather having to re-read data off disk.

Comment: The diff between a 48GB machine and a 24GB machine is likely due to filesystem /OS -level caching using the extra ram.

Comment: [Here is a great tutorial](https://serpro69.medium.com/boosting-performance-of-intellij-idea-and-the-rest-of-jetbrains-ides-cd34952bb978) for creating an in-memory cache for Intellij as well as other speed-ups

Comment: @ecoe Useful. I have found lots of memory and an SSD makes a big difference, even on a Raspberry PI 4 ;)

Answer (score 4):

I've done some experimenting, and found that to decrease GC pauses the following combination works best: `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50`.

I'd also not make the heap too large, 512 or even smaller is OK for me. Otherwise when it becomes full the GC will have to walk it all which takes some time.

Answer (score 2):

You can find good tips here. For example, the speed of switching from IDEA to another app and vice versa was significantly improved after turning the feature "Turn off Synchronize Files" off.

http://hamletdarcy.blogspot.com/2008/02/10-tips-to-increase-intellij-idea.html

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why it has not been mentioned yet - you can enable `Power Save mode`, which turns off many **IJ** background activities, including `Files Synchronization`. Some articles says that it is possible to disable Files Sync in project structure options (like the article in answer by @OJ278), but I was not able to find this option in **IJ 14**, but `Power Save mode` seems to disable it.

I have a quite large code base (**AOSP** source code), so HD activity due to background files synchronization is annoying...

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by `adben` is very helpful for improving the performance in my machine. Though I slightly overrided  it after reading a Dzone article,

```
-server
-Xms2g
-Xmx2g
-XX:NewRatio=3
-Xss16m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:ConcGCThreads=4
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
-XX:+TieredCompilation
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
-ea
```

They improved the performance of large projects by using the above configuration and works flawlessly for our projects too. Lastly, I disabled all the plugins I won't use and that improves the things as well.

Reference: https://dzone.com/articles/the-one-and-only-reason-to-customize-intellij-idea

Answer (score 1):

You can use the intellij's optimizer plugin:

https://zeroturnaround.com/free/optimizer-for-intellij-idea/

With the plugin you can:

- Automatic tune virtual machine options
- Disable class verification
- Clean up system caches
- Configure external build tools
- Validate the latest Oracle JDK
- Skip build and redeploy

Comment: Why down vote? the question is about tuning intellij and this is a solution

Comment: Sadly, the plugin seems to be pulled.

Comment: The plugin is terrible and also this is the reason it was pulled out by Jet brians.

Answer (score 1):

Made a small write up on this topic on medium: https://medium.com/@sergio.igwt/boosting-performance-of-intellij-idea-and-the-rest-of-jetbrains-ides-cd34952bb978

Answer (score 0):

I used this combination and it's working fine in my environment

```
-server
-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:NewSize=512m
-XX:MaxNewSize=512m
-XX:PermSize=512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1
-XX:SurvivorRatio=8
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=65
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-XX:-TraceClassUnloading
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
```

Comment: Don't include `-XX:+UseParNewGC` with recent CLion versions. Invalid option.