# Intellij 12 always do "make"(several seconds) even no code change

Tags: intellij-idea

I just start learning the Intellij. I create a small project and create several java files in a module. There is one thing bothers me, that Intellij always do a "make", which takes about 6-8 seconds, every time before run or debug the java code, no matter if I changed the code or not. I have turned on the "make project automatically" setting in compiler setting. Anyone have a idea?

Comment: After consulting other threads, it seems that it's because of my Kaspersky System Watcher is slowing down the process. After turnning off the "System Watcher", the "make" finish in half a second. I wonder what "suspicious" activity in Intellij stimulate the "System Watcher".

Comment: You should post that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be considered as "temp" answer, because the solution is not optimal. I really don't want to disable such whole "System Watcher" function of Kaspersky.

After consulting other threads, it seems that it's because of my Kaspersky System Watcher is slowing down the process. After turnning off the "System Watcher", the "make" finish in half a second. I wonder what "suspicious" activity in Intellij stimulate the "System Watcher".

Comment: Can you configure Kaspersky to ignore files (.class or all) in your project directories and the IntelliJ settings directory (`$HOME/.IntelliJ*`)?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-192

One of the things mentioned at the very top is about antivirus tools:

[image: Effect of Antivirus on Intellij]

#### Example : Configuring McAfee OAS

Most antiviruses allow specifying folders which are excluded from on-access scan.
For example, on my system with McAfee Enterprise, I found out a folder (`c:\Dev`) that was excluded by the OAS (On Access Scanner):

[image]

Moving *both* the installation folder, as well as the Intellij system folder (`c:\Users\$user\.IntelliJIdea12`) into that folder resulted in a appreciable improvement in IntelliJ performance.

#### Symlinking instead of moving!

If you already have IntelliJ installed then the least disruptive way of doing it is creating Symlinks. For example, for the IntelliJ system folder you would do the following:

1. Move `c:\Users\$user\.IntelliJIdea12` to  `c:\dev\.IntelliJIdea12`
2. Symlink :   `mklink /J c:\Users\$user\.IntelliJIdea12 c:\dev\.IntelliJIdea12`

Do the same for the IntelliJ installation folder.

In my specific case, I was having an issues with large Maven Projects in IntelliJ. This is what worked for me : [Tips for Handling large projects with Maven and IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980885/tips-for-handling-large-projects-with-maven-and-intellij-idea)

Comment: I have tried to exclude every Intellij related folders in Kaskersky, seems no improvement. The Kaskersy "System Watcher" must think the way Intellij working is sneaky.

Comment: Check out [*this*](http://evgeny-goldin.com/blog/intellij-idea-git-kis/) blog post about configuring KIS to exclude IntelliJ. Interestingly, the exclusions include not just IntelliJ, but also maven, jdk and git. Co-incidentally, I use all of those and have all of them excluded.

Is it possible then that the performance issues that you are seeing might be due to something besides Kaspersky ?

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have tried to add about 10 folder exceptions and 20 executable exceptions. No luck. Probably it is about the Kaspersky's System Watcher mechanism. Intellij should at least know what's exactly happening, and not just give the direction to say "uninstall the antivirus software".