# Maven import in Intellij IDEA runs out of memory on a large project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, out-of-memory

Import of Maven project ends with

```
Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

1. I've tried to define an environment variable: `MAVEN_OPTS = -Xmx1g`.
2. I've tried to add `-Xmx1g` to Maven VM options via Settings -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Runner.

Without success. What else can I do?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The solution is to set `-Xmx1g` (or more) in [Maven VM options for importer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-importing.html#d1351343e154) *(yes, it is a separate option!)*. Go to "Settings/Preferences -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing", and find the option there.

[image: Maven importing settings]

Read more on JVM heap size: [(Q) What are the `Xms` and `Xmx` parameters when starting JVMs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14763079/1429387).

Comment: If increasing memory limit doesn't help, check idea.log ([how to find logs?](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)) for errors related to Maven importing.

Comment: Go to Preferences (on Mac) instead of Settings. :)

Comment: Can -Xmx be set to 16384?

Comment: @R11G yes, you can set it to 16384, but note that 16384 bytes are just 16 kilobytes. set it to 16384k if you want 16 megabytes, or 16384m if you want 16 gigabytes.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

if you want in idea, this config will be success.
"Build process heap size (Mbytes)"

preference->Build,Execution,Deployment->Compiler:Build process heap size (Mbytes)

Comment: preference->Build,Execution,Deployment->Compiler:Build process heap size (Mbytes)