# A way to handle large projects with Maven and IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

We have a git repo (mostly in Java) that have hundreds of maven modules. Developers works with Intellij IDEA.
Are there any tools (open source or paid) to allow working in that model? for example: a 'virtual' pom creator that creates working-sets or something similar?
I found this question: [Tips for Handling large projects with Maven and IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980885/tips-for-handling-large-projects-with-maven-and-intellij-idea) but it seems outdated and not exactly answering my problem.

I'm looking for an automatic tool that will reduce manual configuration in intellij.

Comment: The question is: Java/JavaEE modules or OSGi ?

Comment: its Java-Maven modules (not osgi or something like this) in the same repo

Comment: Than an import into IntelliJ should work...You should have configured to recursively import projects in the configuration...

Comment: Are the modules hierarchical? You can try including and excluding them using maven profiles.