# Equivalent JVM options with Oracle J2SE 1.7, for Eclipse 'kepler' 4.3

Tags: eclipse, performance

Trying to improve Eclipse 'Kepler' rel-4.3 IDE's performance on a rather low-powered Netbook (dual-core 1.66MHz Atom N455), running 64-bit Debian based distro.

Found the following 2 previous questions ([q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse), [q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse)) on SE, and tried few combinations.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Adopting the following settings for eclipse.ini, instead of faster startup and operation, I felt some slow-down instead, compared to the default eclipse.ini and use of OpenJDK 6 with IcedTea. So the question is, are any of the suggested operations known to be deprecated or conflict with Oracle Jave SE 1.7

New eclipse.ini tried:

```
-nosplash
-vmargs
-Xincgc
-Xss500k
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms64m
-Xmx200m
-XX:NewSize=8m
-XX:PermSize=80m
-XX:MaxPermSize=150m
-XX:MaxPermHeapExpansion=10m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled
-XX:ConcGCThreads=2
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=2
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=5
-XX:GCTimeRatio=49
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20
-XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=1000
-XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrentAndUnloadsClasses
```

Original eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130521-0416
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into the same thing.  I think it's more a "what's deprecated in your Java version" issue since it's passing most of the commands to Java.  The kepler help file doesn't get to specific with a lot of the commands you and I are passing so that's what I'm thinking.

this is the Kepler help file
http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Fconstant-values.html

one thing I will say is after speed reading the Interweb I think these 2 can't be used at the same time but I dunno.
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+UseParNewGC

I just have the 2nd one in mine

here's where I was reading on it
http://www.fasterj.com/articles/oraclecollectors1.shtml

well, reading it again it looks like you can use both of those 2

take a look here maybe http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get away with as much as these extra args.  Some of the extra ones not in that last url that you used might be deprecated or might not but this didn't crash on me.

```
-d64  
-Xms128m
-Xss4m
-Xmx248m
-Xfuture
-Xincgc
-XX:NewSize=8m
-Xrs
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+UseLargePages
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled
-XX:ConcGCThreads=4
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=5
-XX:GCTimeRatio=49
-XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=1000
-XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrentAndUnloadsClasses
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:PredictedClassLoadCount=16384
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```