# IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 - how to prevent low memory problems on a 32-bit OS (Win 7) with 3GB RAM

Tags: java, maven, memory, intellij-idea, jvm

I have some **memory issues** while **using the IntelliJ IDEA 13.1** (currently 13.1.6), due to **insufficient amount of RAM**. I work on a quite big project and often run some maven builds as well as a web application in debug mode. I've got a **32-bit OS** (Windows 7), **3 GB RAM** and an **SSD**. I use the **JDK 7**.

The Maven builds which are run inside of IntelliJ IDEA fail often due to insufficient memory and I have to resume them from the point of failure.

An alert "**Your computer is low on memory**" is shown by the Windows system often when I perform the Maven builds or try to start the web application using IntelliJ IDEA.

I use the following settings in the configuration file "**idea.exe.vmoptions**" (located in the same directory as the "idea.exe" file):

```
-server
-Xms128m
-Xmx700m
-XX:MaxPermSize=250m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
```

The `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable is set to the following value:

```
-Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

I already **disabled unused plugins** and found out that **it's useful to restart the IDEA after memory-consuming operations**, like e.g. after a Maven build. I also found out that **closing as much other applications as possible** helps a bit, but not always.

However, all aforementioned tricks **didn't eliminate the problems**.

**What are your recommendations**, apart from extending the RAM or changing to a 64-bit OS?

Do you know some **better settings for the "idea.exe.vmoptions" file**?

Comment: If you are running out of ram there is nothing you can do but get more ram and install 64-bit OS. If you have a requirement to test the code in 32 bit OS then install the 32 bit OS in a virtual machine and test it from there.

Comment: I would reduce the amount of max memory specified in the MAVEN_OPTS if possible, as it is also used by IntelliJ for some child processes.

Comment: @Tome This amount has been experimentally determined as the best in our team, because we perform large maven builds. I tested now that a full build of our project **without tests** (i.e. a smaller and shorter build) consumes up to 800 MB RAM when it is run alone from the console. So a full build requires even more RAM and the amount of 1024 MB seems to be reasonable.

Comment: This large amount of RAM might be caused by sub-optimal Javac compiler usage. But if you do need 1024MB for Maven, then you will anyway end up with around 2GB+ for Maven & IntelliJ (and its child processes). Under a 32-bit Windows 7, that will likely cause issues. In short, big build => big RAM.

Comment: @Tome: What do you mean by sub-optimal Javac compiler usage? How can it be optimized? I suppose it's just caused by the fact that it's a very big project. I closed the IntelliJ indeed before the mvn run from console. Apart from the compilation itself and some additional build operations, the tests take very long in a full build with tests.

Comment: Depending on the version of the JDK used, and whether you do fork the compilation process for each module or not, Javac memory can become really huge. See a old review here: http://labs.bsb.com/2011/12/stabilizing-speeding-up-compilation-and-annotation-processing-in-maven-builds/. If you cannot use Eclipse compiler, you can try forking the execution of the Javac compiler (see here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#fork), but then, at the moment it compiles, you have 1 JVM for Maven and 1 for Javac...

Comment: @krm -- upgrade your machine. Your current setup is insufficient for the task at hand. By using a tool like this you are not acting professionally or in the best interest of your client/company. Requisition new hardware -- and force the point, because otherwise you're complicit in offering your company a low return on their investment.