# Moving IntelliJ IDEA caches/index directories to RAM

Tags: caching, intellij-idea, ram, mount

I'm trying to move `caches` and `index` directories from the IntelliJ IDEA config dir to RAM mount point in `/tmp` using symbolic links.

I've added: `tmpfs   /tmp/ramdisk  tmpfs defaults,size=1024M,x-gvfs-show,mode=1777 0 0` to `/etc/fstab`, and replaced `caches` and `index` directories in the intellij config directory with symbolic links pointing to the ram mount point with:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/ramdisk/intellij/caches
$ mkdir /tmp/ramdisk/intellij/index
$ ln -s /tmp/ramdisk/intellij/caches caches #inside intellij config/system dir
$ ln -s /tmp/ramdisk/intellij/index index #inside intellij config/system dir
```

The problem is, on every reboot the mount directories will be deleted from `/tmp` and before mounting I will need to re-create them, otherwise I will get an error `mount: /tmp/ramdisk: mount point does not exist.`
I will also need to re-create caches and index directories or the symbolic links won't work

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to archive? Better read performance? 
Due to linux [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache), this will not increase performance dramatically as you would expect.

I build a project completely on a ramdisk and the build was done in 30 sec.  compared to 32 sec. directly from disk. Wasn't worth the effort.

Comment: Yes, I want to achieve better performance. And also spare the SSD unnecessary read-write operations to prolong it's life.

As for the original question. For now I'm just creating the directories on shell startup from one of my `~/.bash*` files - seems to work fine. But I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: I don't have a better idea. I just wanted to point out, that linux caches a lot behind the scene and I am pretty sure that idea uses memory mapped files for the cache as well. Furthermore,  you have to write the data at some point back to the disk. 

BTW: I run intellij idea every work day for hours and I am using different SSDs since 10 years. Never had problems with SSD life time.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Peter, I will rethink if I need to do this or just leave things to their defaults.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for the sake of answering the question and in case anyone else will stumble on this and will want an answer.

I've ended up using [tmpfiles.d](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/tmpfiles.d.html). Created a new config file for my purposes under `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/` with the following contents:

```
#Type Path                          Mode UID  GID   Age Argument
d     /tmp/ramdisk/intellij/caches  0777 root root  -   -
d     /tmp/ramdisk/intellij/index   0777 root root  -   -
```

And now the directories I need are re-created on each boot.

I will still re-think if I need this at all, since as per comments in the first post it won't make much of a difference on a linux os.

Comment: In the current version it seems to not tolerate symbolic links

Comment: they completely re-did the entire config management since version 2020, so I wouldn't be surprised if this didn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

As @SergioLeone and I pointed out in the comments section, the previous solution doesn't work anymore.
I opted for putting the entire related JetBrains folder in RAM as follows:

```sh
    ~/.cache/JetBrains -> /tmp/intellij/JetBrains
```

Comment: Using this way for some days, and no more SSD noise nor regrets so far...

Comment: I tried that as well right after upgrading to 2020.x when they broke everything :D Back then I haven't observed any significant performance changes as I have previously, so I stopped using this "hack" altogether. Maybe I should try and test this again in 2021.x versions.