# Building workspace with android application takes too long

Tags: android, project, building

In the last few days I have noticed some very strange behavior in my android project:

- After every single little change of an xml-resource, the building of the android application's workspace takes a long time.
- The changing of java source files **doesn't** cause the same slow building

And I have no idea what's going wrong.

I have already cleaned that project but it didn't help.

Is there any way to find out what is making the build process so slow?

P.s.

At about 89% i see the building message ***invoking 'Android Pre Compiler' on 'proj. name'***

Comment: how many Projects you are having in Workspace?

Comment: How many KByte/MBytes of resources do you have in your project?

You should disabled automatic building when modifying/updating resources.

Comment: How long is "too long". Also, did you set any layout files to use the v3.0 SDK? I did this by accident and found it took much longer than it had done previously (my target for current project is v2.2). Once I changed the layouts back to v2.2 things went back to normal build speed.

Comment: @all it's project for v2.2 SDK. There 10 projects in the workspace. I have problems only with one of them, this one has 2.3MB. Disabling automatic building wouldn't be a good solution, because sometimes i add new layouts and id's

Comment: I get this , it's when you have a large amount of xml files in your /layout/ folder or a large amount of files in /drawable/

Comment: I got this same problem when I upgraded Android tools and SDK a while ago. Maddening. It cannot be a problem in my projects since the previous versions built them very quickly. Google "upgraded" a tool and killed performance.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me now. Google upgraded their SDKs and now Eclipse won't get past the "building workspace" phase. Turning off Build Automatically doesn't help, either. Grr.

Answer (score 2):

I've dealt with various eclipse problems before that slowed it down.  A couple things to recommend, enable advanced garbage collection and some of the other items recommended for a performance boost in this article [How can you speed up Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse).

Try enable verbose build output in your preferences for android>build to see if any of your specific resources are the bottleneck.

Although I was unable to find the article, I've read about using eclipse in debug mode and profiling the IDE as you work to see if any plugins are causing interruptions.

Last, I have used the community version of intellij idea 10 http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/ which has strong android support.  It's much faster than eclipse for most tasks, but doesn't have as much embedded android support (you must use ddms as a separate tool, no UI builder, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Increase Xms and Xmx parameter in eclipse.ini file.

My default values was:
-Xms40m
-Xmx256m

My new values are:
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m