# Is the scala eclipse IDE stable enough?

Tags: eclipse, scala

I use eclipse as my scala IDE. But It seems not so good. I can build my project using maven successfully. But eclipse always warn me there's compilation error. Any has experience of scala eclipse plugin ? Thanks BTW I use scala IDE for 2.8.1

Comment: The newest version of the Scala IDE for Scala 2.9 is much better and more stable than the version for 2.8. Try it.

Comment: I have found more personal luck with IntelliJ scala plugin... but I get the impression that eclipse has more people working on the scala plugin, so I suspect it will eventually overtake the IJ scala plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a new Eclipse plug-in which is in the final stages of release, currently in beta 4 which offers numerous improvements including stability. It runs with Scala 2.9.

You can download and try it for yourself. More information and download available here:
http://www.scala-ide.org/

Also, be sure to read on improving Eclipse performance, I find a few of these tweaks makes a big difference. Here are some answers on Stackoverflow regarding that:

[How can you speed up Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse)

[What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659)

Comment: Confirm. Latest version of Scala IDE are quite stable.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using all three major IDEs over the last few days for Scala.

Eclipse is pretty good and perfectly useable although you will encounter a few bugs - silly things like you can't load compiler plugins if you have a space in your plugin folder pathname. It also behaved pretty badly a few times and wouldn't run anything until I restarted Eclipse, but this might be partly because I'm new to it and maybe have been doing something wrong. One thing that is good about Eclipse is that the build time is a lot quicker than for the other two - I think this is because it does and "incremental build". Or maybe it's just more optimized, but it's noticeable.

I would recommend trying the latest version of IntelliJ (10.5). It seems to be the best at the moment with the fewest rough edges, and the only one to have Scaladoc support integrated. I haven't used it much but first impressions are good.

The NetBeans plugin seems to be getting left behind a bit (there's only one guy working on it), which is a shame because it has IMO easily the best code editor for Java, with excellent predictive capabilities which you don't get for Scala at the moment. I'll continue to use it for Java, but the Scala plugin development is a bit sparse. (Although it might be because I'm using a beta version, because that's all that's available right now for Scala 2.9.)