# eclipse performance arm vs intel

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, arm

I'm using Intel Core 2 Duo T5550 with 3 GB ram, and SSD HDD for java development under Ubuntu 64, all is tweaked, but it's still slow. I mean switching between windows and other simple actions, even when it starts up, especially when you open few big projects.
I heard that arm has jazelle and thumb on newer processors, which execute java bytecode directly, and it's fast.
If I switch to such machine would eclipse(java) work faster?

**Edit**:
Thanks for anwserws. I know that Core i7 is at least 4 times faster for java ( just have a look http://infoscreens.org/benchmark_en.html ), but I thought that ARM, which are 2x2GHz and execute java directly would be faster (for java only).

I have Oracle Java, also I used JRockit, but it was strangely crashing during debugging.
I thing I'l buy i7 desktop in near future. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you use maven integration? Depending on the settings that can result in a lot of network traffic.

Comment: Your hardware is enough to run eclipse smoothly. You should have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse, which has a lot of tips.

Answer (score 3):

A Core 2 Duo machine with 3 GB of RAM should have not problem running Eclipse. An ARM chip running standard desktop-oriented OS and JVM is going to be extremely slow. Far slower than your Core 2 Duo machine. Regarding those new ARM instructions, in order for them to be useful, there needs to be a JVM that can work with them. If one exists, it is going to be of specialized sort likely designed for mobile device operating systems.

One common problem that Linux users have with Eclipse is that OpenJDK that comes with Linux distributions just doesn't perform as well as Oracle/Sun JDK. If you haven't installed Oracle JDK, I recommend installing it for use with Eclipse. Your performance problem may just go away.

If it doesn't and you are still considering buying a new machine, an i3/i5/i7 machine would be a far far better choice for a development platform than anything ARM that exists today or likely to exists in the near future.

Oh and one more thing... Eclipse has native components (SWT UI and file I/O) and there isn't a build available for any ARM architecture.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are running low of memory, not just for the application but tocache disk access.  Having more memory, regardless of your process is likely to be your problem.

When your system is running slow is you system waiting on IO or consming CPU. e.g. have a look on `top`.

BTW: I use IntelliJ CE with about 15,000 classes open and it works fine on a machine with 24 GB. ;)

Answer (score 0):

ARM CPU is not as powerful as x86 CPU, so no. Also, I doubt eclipse will run on an ARM machine.