# Building workspace is taking a lifetime

Tags: android, eclipse, resources, build

I'm developing a game that has a lot of drawables. Now I'm designing the levels, and it makes me refresh my project very often after making minor changes. And every time workspace is building very slowly, it makes me lose very much time on just waiting for it to build. Are there any hints on making it faster? Or how can I disable rebuilding of all those resources that do not change from build to build? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not 100% percent sure, but take a look at [Tricks to speed up Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse]). One common solution to your problem is just to disable "Build automatically", but that will, however, rebuild all resources when you're building your application. That means that your last question remains.

Comment: How many project do you have in workspace?

Comment: @Onuray Sahin, I have only one open project right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your environment and version of eclipse, it could be setup to use a small amount of memory on start up. Try tweaking the memory you use and see if that helps. You can do this by starting it from the command line or editing the .ini file (on windows). This blog post touches upon it: http://blog.xam.dk/?p=58

Answer (score 1):

you can disable "Build automatically" in "Project" then you can manually build your app after your changes by "Build project".

Comment: I need to build the project every time I'm making any changes, problem is that I don't want to build resources that I don't change. Is it possible?

Comment: -1 for that. Eclipse does an incremental build, that means it builds only the changed artifacts. Take a look at your project-properties -> Builders and take a look if you have a builder from a 3rd party plugin that are not needed. I'm not very familiar with the mechanism of the android-specific builder, you should also check if that is a general problem or an android specific, to isolate the reason for the slow build.

Comment: the above my solutions is temporarily helps you

Comment: @Tom Seidel, There are 4 builders, three of them are related to Android, I don't think I can disable any of them

Comment: @riser Sorry, but disable building does not resolve the problem of a slow build.

Comment: @Egor: Can you check if the build is also slow if you build a regular java project? -Also check your Error Log view for Exceptions during the build which can slow down the build, too.

Comment: On my Eclipse STS 3.6.4.RELEASE a regular Java project builds normally, but my newbie demo Android project hangs at 83% build. I re-installed STS and the issue remains.