# What can be the reasons that Spring STS hangs?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, javabeans, spring-tool-suite

Sometimes on the start STS hangs.

Does it possible found the reason? May be exists log or possible start in debug mode?
Also how I can distinguish between hangs completely and working very slowly?
Thanks.
P.S. How to fix ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is usually for the same resons descibed here [tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse).
Garbage collection or validation.

- If you have enough RAM I would suggest that you set -Xmx768m or higher (in eclipse.ini).
- Under Windows->Preferences->Validation you can switch off a lot of stuff.

Comment: What about local history, some kind of local database that Eclipse use? May be wrong info in these files can produce problems?

Comment: Of note: if you are on a Mac you want to edit sts.ini and that lives inside of th STS application package.

Answer (score 2):

My STS hanged when I tried to start it. Couldn't tell why.

Doing this fixed things for me:
Shut down eclipse and then navigate to /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources and remove the .snap file.

Courtesy: https://doctorjw.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/eclipse-locking-upnot-responding-try-this/

Answer (score 1):

There's a log file I think it's in .metadata/.log in the workspace used. To see if memory causes the issue, and it usually does, try to run jconsole (part of the JDK) and connect to the running eclipse process, and see the memory stats.

Answer (score -2):

**Ensure that STS is running with admin privileges to avoid permission problems.**

In ubuntu edit the following line in STS.desktop launch file:

```
Exec=gksu /etc/springsource/sts-3.4.0.RELEASE/STS
```

Complete file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=STS
Comment=SpringSource Tool Suite
Exec=gksu /etc/springsource/sts-3.4.0.RELEASE/STS
Icon=/etc/springsource/sts-3.4.0.RELEASE/icon.xpm
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```