# STS crash when selecting the first workspace

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I'm using STS for the first time and I can't select a workspace because the program freezes.

[Window froze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FmIa.png)

What should I do?

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026120/what-can-be-the-reasons-that-spring-sts-hangs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible for Gradle projects in Eclipse/STS to resolve dependencies to other Gradle projects in the same workspace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282985/is-it-possible-for-gradle-projects-in-eclipse-sts-to-resolve-dependencies-to-oth)

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

1. Run STS.exe
2. Below STS window opend

[image]

3. Click on Browse button & change new project workspace location as below

[image]

4. Click to OK button.

Comment: I could not click on browse button because the window does not respond. I tried running as administrator and now it works.

Comment: What should I do with this question now?

Comment: You does not have to do anything for this question. If someone face such issue then they will try to fix issue using this resolution.