# Speed Up Eclipse when editing files with 2000+ lines

Tags: eclipse

When i edit large files in eclipse (around 2000+ lines), editing the file becomes very slow.
The text will appear a couple seconds after i type it in.

I tried it in an editor like notepad++ and it handles the file fine.

I have looked into this question for speeding up eclipse, but I haven't had much luck a with them. [How can you speed up Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse)

Any thoughts on this is really appreciated, as i know several of my friends run into this issue as well.

Comment: There is a related eclipse bug report https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=283614

Comment: Thanks for that tip, By uninstalling jdt I was able to speed editing by about 50%, it still lags but not as much as it did before. Im doing remote editing as well, so i wasn't able to edit it on a per project basis. Id still would like to find a way to bring it up to normal, but this does help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the code folding feature, If you really don't need Code Folding disable it.

Window->Preferences->PHP-Editor->Code Folding and uncheck Code folding feature.

Comment: thanks dude, you save my day, I've been face this problem over a month!

Answer (score -2):

Rather than trying to speed up Eclipse, it might be better stylistically to break your 2000+ line file into several smaller files. If that file is a Java class, for instance, you probably have a God Object and need to break it up anyway.

Assuming this is a java file, the reason it's slow while Notepad++ is fast, is that Notepad++ is just displaying the file. Eclipse is compiling, checking for compiler warnings, running bug finders/checkstyle/whatever you have installed, etc, some of which takes time, and can take a lot of time on a large file.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts. actually were are on php and breaking the file out into many smaller pieces although is the best way in a perfect world, in our case I don't see it as an option.