# Ways to optimize my Eclipse ini file?

Tags: java, eclipse

This is what my Eclipse.ini currently looks like

```
-startup
plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.101.R34x_v20081125.jar
-install
D:\IBM\WID7
--launcher.library
plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.101.R34x_v20080731
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vm
jdk\jre\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xquickstart
-Xms512m
-Xss2048k
-Xmaxf0.1
-Xminf0.05
-Xmx1800m
-Xmnx64m
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-Xscmx96m
-Xshareclasses:name=IBMSDP_%u
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-Dorg.eclipse.jdt.core.javamodelcache.ratio=0.0625
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dosgi.bundlefile.limit=100
-Xincgc
```

What changes can I make to speed up Eclipse even further? I am still seeing some performance issues, espectially on large builds - take a really long time.

Comment: The first change I'd make is to add memory to your computer. Then I'd replace the hard disk with an SSD. Those two changes will probably make a much bigger difference than any INI-tweaking you could do.

Comment: This is a corporate VM, can't really do much. It's a 32-bit system and it already has 4 GB ram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for the mac changing the required java version for osgi to 1.6 helped for me:

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
```

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse) contains a lot of tips, read all the comments.