# The reason of unnecessary crashes of eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I have a clean `Ubuntu 13.04` installation on my machine. The machine has a pretty good configuration (e.g., Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3820 CPU @ 3.60GHz, 1600 MHz, 32 GB DDR3 RAM, etc.)

I use `Juno Service Release 2`, however it sometimes crashes without any reason at random times. It makes me really sick. I used the newer versions of Eclipse and had the same problem earlier.

I am not sure whether the source of the problem Ubuntu or Eclipse. Is there any solution for it?

Do I need to just get used to it, if I want to keep using `Eclipse`?

Comment: Why -1, please leave a comment so that I can update or remove the question.

Comment: Yeah I have the same problem with Ubuntu 13.04. I am in need of an answer as well

Comment: Probably some eclipse bug, but try using Oracle's Java (just in case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very difficult to diagnose Eclipse crashes without more details, it can be a bug... Nevertheless, I would recommend to make some experiments, such as using the latest java versions to run eclipse and also take a look at your "eclipse.ini" and try to optimize a bit your JVM configurations, e.g.: increase memory for Eclipse (you have 32GB, you can allocate quite a lot). The following references are a good source of "tips and tricks" to improve your setup:

- [What are the best JVM settings for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse?lq=1)
- [Ways to optimize my Eclipse ini file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522738/ways-to-optimize-my-eclipse-ini-file)
- [How can you speed up Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse?lq=1)