# Unable to start Eclipse Helios

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, helios

I just installed Eclipse Helios. Once I unzipped and opened the Eclipse it asked for my workspace. I selected the path and it said ok. It opened the workspace and said workbench loading and suddenly the Eclipse IDE closed and in the main Eclipse folder I got a `hs_err_pid6040` text file which appeared as log.

Below is the content of the logfile. I'm just including a part of it. The rest shows process, other threads, VM arguments, Env variables and my system config info. I don't understand what the error is or how to debug. Please help.

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (nmethod.cpp:1707), pid=6040, tid=6344
#  Error: guarantee(cont_offset != 0,"unhandled implicit exception in compiled code")
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10.0-b19 mixed mode windows-amd64)
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000006a7d400):  JavaThread "Worker-1" [_thread_in_Java, id=6344, stack(0x000000000bac0000,0x000000000bbc0000)]

Stack: [0x000000000bac0000,0x000000000bbc0000]
[error occurred during error reporting (printing stack bounds), id 0xc0000005]


[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xc0000005]
```

Comment: Did you install the eclipse bundle that contains a JRE? If you did, did you get the correct JRE for your operating system? ( This appears to be a 64 bit JRE - are you running on a 32 bit OS ? )

Comment: No.Its all 64 bit including JDk, eclipse

Comment: This bug was was posted back in 2008: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do;jsessionid=89e14a03a0c9bf9a6bf4996951d?bug_id=6737764  SUGGESTION: Upgrade your JDK/JRE

Comment: i see a bug raised. No solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: i see a bug raised. No solution?

A: You didn't look closely enough.  The bug was noted in your version (6.04), and fixed in subsequent releases:

- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6739357

Upgrade your JVM :)

Comment: Thanks Paulsm4. I have another question now. I have my weblogic pointing to this JDK. when i uninstall java 1.6.0_04 and reinstall another version say for example 1.6.0_23, should i reinstall weblogic? or make change in some specified config files? if so, what files?

Comment: No - uninstall/reinstall should more or less happen "automagically".  If it doesn't, you can configure your "default" Java in the registry (Windows) or `update-alternatives --config java` (Linux).

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have multiple JDKs installed on your system and Eclipse is picking up the incorrect one ?

Please check the VM by editing your eclipse.ini (This should be inside the folder where you extracted or installed Eclipse Helios)

In order to do so please see the documentation [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse?#eclipse.ini).

In short, you'll need to add or correct the `-vm` argument inside the eclipse.ini to point to the javaw.exe of the JDK you want to use, like so :

```
-vm
c:/Program Files/Java/jdk/bin/javaw.exe
```

Correct the path above to point to your javaw.exe.

Thought it's out of the scope of OP's question, you may want to try thinking about using the path of the jvm.dll instead of javaw.exe. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/316535/325742)