# Eclipse workspace disk size just grows and grows

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse

I use Eclipse on WINDOWS, have a simple c++ project, and the size of the workspace folder just grows and grows. I have like 30 MB workspace size, with a project of just 100KB of source files.

What are the settings in Eclipse that affect the size of the workspace. How can I limit the size and speed up Eclipse?

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse keeps in workspace all settings, like font you are using. 30 MB is no so much, deal with it.

Read this to speed up [How can you speed up Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse)

Also you can read this http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html

Comment: "deal with it." - I suspect he is dealing with it since he wants to understand what that bloat consists of... rather than ignoring it