# Eclipse : How to reduce jar scope

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, kettle

I have integrated Kettle in a project I develop with Eclipse/Tomcat.
The startup is awfully long because Kettle initialization browse all jars for xml config files.
He's actually browsing all the eclipse jar (943 jars) so it takes a very long time.

Is there a way to avoid this problem in eclipse configuration.
Server classpath is limited to the JRE and the tomcat bootstrap.

Regards
Jer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe key was to register another user.dir at launch of the server (-Duser.dir=...) in the launch configuration of my tomcat server.

Answer (score 1):

I think `-Xverify:none` will solve your problem, but I suggest you do more tuneups to your Eclipse setup with hints from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse)

Comment: To be added in the eclipse.ini?

Comment: Yes, eclipse.ini, also check if you have enough heap memory allocated etc. Check on the other thread