# my eclipse indigo is too slow while other programs are fast

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I don't know why my eclipse is too slow, especially when shifting between tab files yet my other programs opened perform very fast. Can anyone help me or know the reason why? 
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/316265/1069068

Comment: You should include at least some information about your environment: operating system, versions of Eclipse, distro, ... Eclipse 4.x had performance problems in the past, but seem to be solved (mostly) in Eclipse 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

go to  your `eclipse-home --> eclipse.ini` and change the value of `-XX:MaxPermSize` to `-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`