# Best VM argument Configuration for Windows 7 - i5 processor - hp laptop

Tags: eclipse

Could someone tell me the best eclipse VM arugments and configuration for the below Hardware configuraiton

Memory: 8GB
Bit : 64-bit
Processor: i5
Laptop : HP
Model: ProBook 4430s

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna configure -vm parameters or eclipse.ini, I am not quite experienced on that.. But I got you these links that seem to be quite useful:

[How can you speed up Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse)

http://www.beyondlinux.com/2011/06/25/speed-up-your-eclipse-as-a-super-fast-ide/

Comment: I can only work on Windows 7 OS and not intending to install any other OS. Project has been build with maven and has several libraries too. But i observed the same project and the application gets started in linux box very faster which has the same configuration. That's what surprises me..Both the machines has same eclipe version, ram and only difference is the OS. so i would like to know which the best way to configure eclipse so that it performs better than in linux or atleast works similar to linux.