# how to improve the performance of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am using eclipse juno version. At first it working very slowly. so i changed some values in eclipse.ini file to enhance the speed.

The changes are,

from

```
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

to

-Xms1024m
   -Xmx1024m

Still eclipse performance is poor. How to speed up the eclipse performance. any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tricks to speed up Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/tricks-to-speed-up-eclipse)

Comment: There were some known performance problems in Juno which are fixed in Kepler (4.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the following value as well and then try

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

Add `-Xverify:none` to `eclipse.ini` file.

It will cutdown eclipse startup time by telling VM not to validated the .class files it is loading.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable unwanted plugins if you don't use them on a usual basis.