# STS taking long time to start

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

Can any one please suggest, Why `STS(Version: 3.4.0.RELEASE)` taking long time to start.

My PC Deatails:

- Window 7,
- Ram : 4GB,
- i3 processor,
- 32 bit O.S

STS.ini Details:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vmargs
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
```

I already searched for this issue but i can't got any good solution,any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Check the logs, maybe it say something. Also try switch into an empty workspace, maybe something is slowing it down (eg: indexing maven repository).

Comment: Thanks @gerrytan, i checked my log file (workspace\.metadata\.log)
Here is below exception :
-java.net.UnknownHostException: download.springsource.com

Comment: Is there any other place to check log file.

Comment: SSD is your choice. Even for my 7-years old Vaio with new SSD it started loading and working times faster.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

May be you can try following

- Increase from `-Xms40m` to `-Xms500m`. It indicates jvm to start with 500 Mb memory.
- Try with STS –clean
- Remove file `<WORK_SPACE>/.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects\.markers.snap`, because sometimes eclipse will constantly polling a fairly large snapshot of some of your projects.
- You can disable ‘Refresh workspace on startup’ option in `Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Startup and Shutdown`
- Disable automatic builds under Install/updated and Label Decorator
- Upgrading to the `latest JVM` supported on your machine this may help as well
- `Disable all validations` under preferences unless you need them

[image]

I hope these tips will help you for sure :) .

Comment: Thanks @Jayasagar, Your information's are really so helpful. I tried all of yours steps,but I don't realized any change.

Comment: May be you can try one more 'Disable virus scanners, or at least configure any virus scanner to not scan JAR files of your application and Eclipse on read access'

Comment: I installed MacAfee in my PC. Can you please tell me, how to restrict not to scan JAR files.

Comment: Thanks @Jayasagar,STS now start normally by disabling my antivirus. My Friend is there any alternate solution rather than "Disable virus scanners".

Answer (score 2):

My STS was taking a long time, 5 minutes just to boot up, in spite of running on a high performance SSD machine. So I modified the STS.ini with Xms=200m(original value was 40m) and it started booting up real fast in under 30 seconds.

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Xms300m
-Dosgi.module.lock.timeout=10
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Xmx1200m
```

Answer (score 0):

STS is based off eclipse so some the answers on this site re [speeding up eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/how-can-you-speed-up-eclipse) will help.

- I noticed a great speed up by installing a Solid State Drive. This
  speeds up your whole machine.
- Using the latest oracle JDK speeds things up for me too.