# Eclipse Kepler freezes when saving

Tags: java, eclipse

I have recently had a problem with Eclipse. I am developing a java application. It suddenly freezes whenever I try to save a file. Indeed, it happens to some files in my project while it works fine with the others. I have checked the .log file in my workspace and there is no error message! I tried to disconnect my project from GIT, but the problem persisted. It drives me crazy. I have to restart Eclipse many times everyday.

Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Re-download Eclipse, import your old projects, and give it another spin. This isn't really a technical support website.

Comment: Try turning "build automatically" off.

Comment: @ChrisZhang actually `software tools commonly used by programmers` *are* on-topic according to http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. On the other hand re-download seems like a good idea to start with.

Comment: If not, more details on which files cause the problem and which don't would be the way forward.

Comment: @alex I didn't say it was off-topic, just that his error seems to be more of a clueless blunder (given the lack of detail) than a focused and researched inquiry about an issue.

Comment: @ChrisZhang fair enough :)

Comment: I tried all the above suggestions, but it didn't work. All the files have the same imports but the problem seems to happen with large files (+900 lines)
@alex: what kind of details would you like to know?

Comment: If Kepler does not work for you, maybe try Juno (Eclipse 4.2) instead. Sometimes the latest versions have some unresolved issues.

Comment: You workspace log file (the .metadata/.log file) should provide some clues as to what's happening, like exception stack traces and so on. It will also contain information about your system (OS, processor architecture, eclispe and java version etc..). Please check this log and perform a minimum of investigation from it, then you can add what you found and did to your question, so others have a chance to provide meaningful answers, which is currently precluded by the lack of details.

Answer (score 1):

Such kind of issues should provide all related info: OS, Java, Eclipse version, list of plugins installed. Example of file saved. CPU, RAM size, memory setting for Eclipse.

Without knowing those details some recommendation would be to analyze and try to find the cause by comparing:

- try on other PC,
- with other Java version
- other Eclipse version
- the same Eclipse version without any additional plugins.
- increase Eclipse memory settings

Check if it is build related by disabling automatic build.

Check if there are "Save Action" configured in Preferences.

and so on.

- maybe some plugin causes that, but usually people just go with new Eclipse instance instead of comparing different plugins combinations.

See also [How can you speed up Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/how-can-you-speed-up-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, it's worked. I created a new workspace and import it my project to it. Everything works well since then, like a magic! It seems the problem occurred because my workspace was too old. I have been working on the same workspace since more than 2 years. 
Thanks fellows for your time to help.