# Should I use JRE or JDK in Eclipse for PHP development?

Tags: java, php, eclipse

I am currently using JRE in Eclipse. I am wondering if using JDK is going to speed up Eclipse. I use Eclipse only for PHP development, and not for any Java-related work.

Comment: Related: [How can you speed up Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/316265/897024)

Answer (score 6):

Using the JDK won't speed up Eclipse. If you aren't doing any Java development work, there's no reason to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Download a JDK if you're doing real Java development as you'll need it for that. If you're doing C/C++, PHP, or something else, you might never need it and can just use a Java Runtime Environment (JRE). Eclipse already comes ready to use that and probably already works without you doing anything.

To speed up eclipse,keep JDK on a RAM disk.It just needs 300mb space and it doesnt required by other programs.

Comment: Can I add JRE on a RAM disk or does it have to be JDK? I think the same rule applies while running JRE or JDK off the RAM disk - whether it's for Java or non-Java development. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Usually, when you only care about running Java programs on your browser or computer you will only install JRE. It's all you need. On the other hand, if you are planning to do some Java programming, you will also need JDK.Sometimes, even though you are not planning to do any Java Development on a computer, you still need the JDK installed,for deploying web apps!So go for JDK to add on RAM disk ,it will be helpful. Thank you.