# ggts file search slower due to growing number of files

Tags: grails, sproutcore, ggts

I am using GGTS as ide for Grails and Sproutcore, the file search function in my workspace is becoming slow, because the number of files to be searched is growing. E.g. it was 45.000 files and nowaday it is 100.000 files. How can I clean/refresh the number of files? I noticed in the Sproutcore part a big amount of files in the stage folder. It seems there are a lot of versions copies.

Comment: Are all of these files a source files and have to be loaded to ggts project?

Comment: To my knowledge, No, I started working on the project with approx. 45000 files, and nowadays it searches 100000 files? These 55000 can not be source files.

Comment: Please use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/how-can-you-speed-up-eclipse to configure your GGTS which is similar to Eclipse.

Comment: If you are using the SproutCore Ruby build tools, it can help to stop the development server, delete the projects tmp folder and then restart the server.

Comment: Additionally, as SproutCore is moving away from the Ruby build tools, it might make sense to try out the NodeJS based build tools, https://github.com/sproutcore/build-tools

Comment: Thx, I'll try both suggesties.

Comment: Just a thought, I noticed that the number of files becomes twice the amount it was before, the moment we used/moved the git files to another server.

Comment: The sproutcore build command fills the subfolders tmp/build, tmp/cache, /tmp/staging with a new subfolder for each new version number, and there is no cleanup, so the tmp folder size keeps growing. And the tmp folder is part of the GGTS project. Our buid command file contains the following lines: rm -R tmp/build and sproutcore build $appName --build $BUILDNUMBER. Please some advice.

Comment: Added rm -R tmp/build, rm -R tmp/cache, rm -R tmp/staging. GGTS search has now only 4.700 files to be searched. Solved.