# Program running slow/eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, lag

I've come across a couple of issues whilst making my program. The first one is that Eclipse(Mars 4.5.0) seems to lag specifically when I open the preferences, and then sometimes whilst normally operating it (i.e. Just writing code). Should I allocate more memory to solve this problem?

Secondly, it is sort of a tie in, my program(Java) has been slowing down as i progress with making it. I understand that having several `for-loops` as well as `nested-loops` would cause some significant lag to the program, as of right now this is as efficient as I can get though. So is there a way to allocate more memory to the program, or would I even have to allocate more memory in the first place?

Thanks in advance. I'm not very knowledgable in this area of programming, so apologize if it seems like a silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add more heap space to your specific program you can go into run configurations> arguments and under VM arguments add -Xmx1500m  This will reserve plenty of space for your program. As for eclipse being slow, I would suggest preforming a [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135). That is what I always do whenever my applications are running slow. If that doesn't help, follow [this link](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-allocate-more-memory-to-eclipse.html) to allocate more memory to eclipse

Answer (score 0):

i executed eclipse from command and now its speed is awesome ! 
in

> eclipse/plugins/

directory and

```
java -jar org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
```

file name -> launcher v20...  is deferent in deferent versions

hope its help
alternative answer is
[How can you speed up Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/how-can-you-speed-up-eclipse?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top)