# Eclipse hangs and doesn't respond while trying to open multiple .js files

Tags: node.js, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a node.js application set up on my eclipse. when i launch my eclipse the CPU utilization and memory usage seems to be fine, but when I try to open 4 - 5 .js files from the project explorer, Eclipse hangs and stops responding with a memory out of bound error message.So i reset my eclipse.ini file with :
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
2048m
But still, my eclipse doesn't respond and the memory utilization hits too high crossing 2048MB and almost 98% CPU utilization. I couldn't get started with this. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using other plugins and their background jobs may be running. Like indexers which can eat up lot of your memory.

Please follow the steps mentioned in the articles below and i am sure your scenario will improve

http://www.nicolasbize.com/blog/7-tips-to-speed-up-eclipse/

[How can you speed up Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/how-can-you-speed-up-eclipse)