# Eclipse Neon Pathetically Slow

Tags: eclipse, performance

Is there a way to identify what's going on with Eclipse when a file is saved?

[image]

My eclipse runs extremely slow (takes close to 3 minutes to save a file). Simple addition of a space in a file and save, it keeps saying 'Updating Navigator Content Viewer' and 'Remote System Explorer Operation' and simply freezes.

I am running on a powerful system with 16 gigs of ram and assigned 1 gig for eclipse. The way it performs is simple unacceptable and planning to switch all my projects to NetBeans rather than wasting hours on save.

Any hints on fixing this are appreciated.

Comment: What kind of file? Where is it located? Is that inside the workspace? Are you doing anything with the Remote System Explorer?

Comment: I am doing nothing out of the ordinary. Just a simple .java or a .xhtml file, located in a simple JSF web project on my local disk. No, this file is not inside my workspace, but both my workspace and projects are within the same drive.

Answer (score 4):

Finally resolved the issue by getting rid of Eclipse.

Moved all my projects to NetBeans 8.2. Its a big relief to see my projects getting saved in a split second.

Coming to Eclipse, it is powerful and exceptional on all aspects other than the slowness during save. However, this frustrating issue alone makes me rate Eclipse 1 (may be 0) on a scale of 10. Cannot expect a developer to wait for 2 minutes to save a file (on a 16 gig system, with 4 gigs assigned to Eclipse) which would drag the productivity drastically.

Looks like this issue is not something new as I have seen many posts on various forums regarding the same. I don't understand how Eclipse never gave a thought on this slowness issue.

Comment: Developers of Eclipse never gave a thought to the slowness issue because, for mysterious reasons, it's never slow for them. Search their Bug Reports for "SLOW", and every one of them is marked "Closed" as "WORKSFORME".

Maybe they're just super patient?

Answer (score 0):

First you should try to look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/316535/5669411) so:

- Check if it is the latest version (I personally run Neon 4.6 and it takes about 2 minutes to parse and save a 55MB file)
- Check your JDK/JRE

You should also try to see if it doesn't come from your drive...

If you still have the problem, I suggest you look at the other Eclipse versions (Mars...)