# Eclipse stuck on "Building workspace"

Tags: java, eclipse

I am extremely new to Java, I just started a course about a day ago so and I don't understand some of the jargon on some of the same questions that were asked on this subject here previously. This is the 2nd project (first one worked fine) I've made and it's stuck, it says "user operation is waiting for 'building workspace' to complete". It's been stuck at 19% since yesterday. I completed uninstalled Eclipse and installed it again and that same project reappeared and is still at 19%. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can try to modify the eclipse.ini file and assign some more heap space to eclispe: see as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/how-can-you-speed-up-eclipse?rq=1

Comment: I would suggest reducing the scope of the problem / code that you have written.  That is, if you comment out most of the application, then does it work?  If so, gradually add pieces back in.  When you uncomment a section and it stops working, then you have found your culprit.

Aside from that you will need to revise your question to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It’s MacOS, I changed the path from the default to my downloads folder because some suggested on other forums to change the path. I cannot open any of the other files because it’s waiting for the other file to load and won’t process anything else until that’s done I’m suspecting. I’ll try and modify the eclipse.ini file

Comment: The problem is most likely somewhere in the workspace, not the Eclipse files itself.  Can you recreate the workspace from a fresh checkout from your source repository?

Answer (score -1):

you need first to mention us your OS version (windows or Linux ?) and the path of your workspace , if it's Windows , so maybe it's secured against write access, so try to run eclipse with **Administrator privilage**.