# Eclipse Oxygen building workspace takes time

Tags: eclipse, workspace, eclipse-oxygen

Im using xpx 13 windows 10.
In the past 2 days eclipse takes too much time to build workspace or have typing lag.

Any tips how to solve it?

Comment: This can be due to many reasons, including issues with your hardware and RAM limitations. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/how-can-you-speed-up-eclipse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you speed up Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/how-can-you-speed-up-eclipse)