# eclipse not showing git repository status

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

we're using eclipse Oxygen.1a, release 4.7.1a. Earlier my eclipse was running slow and i was trying some things to speed it up(like disabling automatic updates, disabling validations etc. from this thread: [How can you speed up Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/how-can-you-speed-up-eclipse)). I also tried steps mentioned in few blogs. I dunno which exact thing did this, but now i can no more see the git sync status for my projects in package explorer view, it looks like this:

[image]

Whereas earlier, against the project name it used to show [master], up or down arrows -> indicating the sync status with remote repo. It also used to show a ">" sign indicating the file is changed when compared to git repo...
It doesn't show any of these properties any more. (Below is an image how it used to look like earlier - project name removed):
[image]

What i tried so far, i restored eclipse properties to its defaults and also tried to google this issue, but to no avail.
If anyone has faced similar issue and can help, that will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look for errors at `<workspace>/.metadata/.log`.

Comment: I have tons of java.io.IOException 503 when connecting to http://marketplace.eclipse.org in the logs. Also i see few other errors while connecting to our organizations internal maven/gradle repo

Comment: Probably not related, look for egit, jgit or git related exceptions.

Comment: Thank you Luis, i can see a lot of "Resource is out of sync with the file system", "org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.CheckoutConflictException", "org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException ... A problem occurred evaluating root project" - does this mean i have to create a new workspace?

Comment: Not yet :-p :-S, try 'Refresh' in the workspace or starting Eclipse with `-clean` option.

Comment: Did Refresh and clean start, no change :(

Comment: Go to `Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Label decorations` to see if `Git` is enabled.

Comment: hey that was it :-) You did it, thank you, yes git was disabled there! Thank you so much, please post this as answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to
`Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Label decorations`
to see if `Git` is enabled.